# How to Import from parent directory Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a file from the main directory using python. I tried several methods but no luck :(.

**My file directory**

```
|_ api
    |__init__.py
    |_api1.py
    |_api2.py
    |_api3.py
    |_api4.py
    |_api5.py
    |_api6.py
|__init__.py
|_api.py
|_db_ops.py
```

**Challenge**

I am trying to import some methods of `api.py` into `api1.py` and `api2.py`.

**The solutions I have found were:**

```
1. Add __ini__.py file
   I have added them as you can see but did not work.

2. import using `import api`
   did not worked rather throws an error **ModuleNotFoundError**

3. import using 'from . import api'
   throws an error "cannot import from unknown module"

4. even tried to create a parent folder **test** and then tried with import test.apicall  but still did not worked!
```

Any help.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running `api1.py` and `api2.py`

Comment: `api1.py` and `api2.py` are imported to the `api.py` file based on routes

Comment: The first step would probably be to use the correct file name `__init__.py`, with a "t".

Comment: @fsimonjetz sorry, my bad, its `init`

Comment: Sounds like you have a circular import, when you are trying to import `api1.py` into `api.py` and `api.py` into `api1.py`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing

Comment: @Tzane yeah exactly, and the answer you tagged. I am trying the same procedure but have no success,

Comment: You could try restructuring your code such that the common functions needed in both modules are defined in a separate module to avoid the circular import all together

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the file name is `__init__.py` and not `__ini__.py`.
by default, you only can import directory from the same level or below where you are using the python command.
example:

```
myproject/
  project/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  bar.py
```

if the terminal in myproject and i run python project/foo.py, foo can import bar.py , but if i am myproject/project and i run python foo.py, foo cannot import bar.py

to change the default you can use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path of my dir')
```

Comment: thats what i am also wondering. I am in the myproject and running the command python project/foo.py it returns error as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'`

Comment: just a question. The file is api.py and the directory is also api/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to run a script in a lower-level folder, Python will not let you do it. On the other hand, let's say for simplicity you have the folder structure

```
mypackage/
   subpackage/
      __init__.py
      api1.py
   __init__.py
   api.py
```

If `api.py` looks like the following

```
def foo(a):
    print(a)
```

then in `api1.py` you can have a relative import like

```
from ..api import foo as f
```

Then you *can't*, however, run `api1.py` as a script, but you can use `f` as a function to extend things in `api1.py` or write a script with the content

```
from mypackage.subpackage.api1 import f
```

so in that case, it will *look* like the function `foo` was in `api1.py`.

I'll note that this was heavily inspired by the Python-documentation on relative imports... (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)