# "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube' (most likely due to a circular import)"

Tags: python, importerror, pytube

Here is the code:

```
import pytube as p
video_url = input("Enter the link: ")
youtube = p.YouTube(video_url)
filters = youtube.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension="mp4")
filters.get_highest_resolution().download("MyPath")
```

I tried to write a code to download a YouTube video. But it's throwing an error saying:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube' (most likely due to a circular import)`

[image: full error message]

I even copy-pasted codes from the internet, re-installed Python, and re-installed pytube but none worked. What's even more frustrating is, that it was working fine when I executed it a few months before.

Comment: Please do not post pictures, post code and error message! [mre]

Comment: change your file name.

Comment: @nfn should be right, if after changing the filename you are getting a ***different*** error you must edit the answer to make it possible to help you.

Comment: ok I will not post pictures . This is my first time asking question here. And yes i did change the file name . The error didn't change

Comment: my suggestion: search C-drive and delete all files "pytube.py". After that install my version: `!pip install git+https://github.com/JNYH/pytube`. More info: https://github.com/JNYH/pytube/blob/master/pytube_sample_code.ipynb

Answer (score 6):

> *AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube' (most likely due to a circular import)*

Did you notice how is your file named? `pytube.py`. This may have caused the [`circular import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing), since Python is trying to `import` the `pytube.py` file itself.

---

I would suggest you to read [`this`](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-circular-import/#:%7E:text=Generally%2C%20the%20Python%20Circular%20Import,and%20eventually%20throws%20an%20error.) and [`this`](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/), the first one is exactly your case.

---

So the short answer is:

## Change your file name!

And when I say **change** I mean that you have to **rename** your file, and not to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I did notice it and I changed the name but it didn't work :(

Comment: You are getting the same error? This is very strange, could you edit your answer with what you've tried and what did you get?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error . I changed the file name to videodownload.py and the error didn't change

Comment: Try to change it to myFileWithUnusualName.py, since there may be a module called videodownload imported by pytube with the scope to download videos.

Comment: ok I will try it out and tell you

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pavit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python programs\pavithra.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube as p
  File "c:\Users\pavit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python programs\pytube.py", line 3, in <module>
    youtube = p.YouTube(video_url)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: Ok, you didn't rename your file. You must still delete pytube.py

Comment: @quamrana probably understood the problem, try deleting pytube.py, and in the future remember to avoid files with the same name of a module used in them. If it worked accept my answer, otherwise feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: ok I will try that out

Comment: @PavithraE if it worked please accept my answer, otherwise feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still giving me that error, I thought it was resolved but I keep getting it no matter what I tried :(

Comment: And sometimes the error wont show up but gets replaced by[ AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'filter']

Comment: The other AttributeError doesn't depend on it