# Tkinter interface does call Function in Main code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi guys I'm making a Python3 program that makes some ZPL tags.
And I have two codes, one with the main code and another with the Interface (that I use Tkinter to make it). So my problem is that my Interface is not working well with the main code. So, it's confusion so the code main is:

```
from ctypes import cast
import requests
import shutil
import sys
import csv
import os
from tkinter import *
from classGui import ProgGui

modelo_etiqueta_mm =[
    [20,35], [30,75], [50,105]
]

modelo_etiqueta_in =[
    [0.787402,1.37795], [1.1811,2.95276], [1.9685,4.13386]
]

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'base_produtos.csv')


def main_shell():
    # Code

def ProgGui():
    pass

def cria_etiqueta(pos_coluna, pos_linha, produto, cod_barra):
    #Code

def busca_produto(p_cod_produto):
    #Code

def cria_linha(p_qtd_etiqueta,p_cod_produto, p_linhas):
    #Code

def cria_zpl(p_cod_produto, p_qtd_etiqueta, p_modelo_etiqueta):
    #Code

def geraPdf():
    #Code

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(sys.argv)

    # separa a execução, se chamar com parametro é execução por shell
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2: # aqui fazes a verificacao sobre quantos args queres receber, o nome do programa conta como 1
        print('Execução de shell.')
        main_shell()
    else :
        print('Execução com Interface')
        gui = ProgGui()
        #gui.mainloop()

    # encerra execução
    sys.exit()
```

And the Ui is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ProgGui:
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__()
        
        quantEtiquetas = IntVar()
        codInt = IntVar()

        master.title('Etiquetas')
        master.geometry('500x200')
        self.pad = ttk.Frame(app, padding=100)

        self.nomeProg = ttk.Label(app, text="Etiquetas").grid(sticky='E')
        self.etqTxt = ttk.Label(app, text="Cod do produto").grid(column=0, row=1 )
        self.quanTxt = ttk.Label(app, text="Quant de etiquetas").grid(column=0, row=2)

        self.entryCod = ttk.Entry(app, textvariable=codInt).grid(column=1, row=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.entryqantEtiquetas = ttk.Entry(app, textvariable=quantEtiquetas).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=20, pady=20)
        
        self.btnQuit = ttk.Button(app, text="Quit", command=app.destroy).grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.btnPdf = ttk.Button(app, text="Gera Pdf", command= geraPdf).grid(column=0, row=3)
        

app = Tk()
tela = ProgGui(app)
app.mainloop()
```

So when I run the main it does not work and give the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "zpl_printer_test_object.py", line 40, in <module>
    from classGui import ProgGui                                                
  File "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/etiqueta/classGui.py", line 39, in <module>          
    tela = ProgGui(app)                 
  File "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/etiqueta/classGui.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.btnPdf = ttk.Button(app, text="Gera Pdf", command= geraPdf).grid(column=0, row=3)
NameError: name 'geraPdf' is not defined
```

I don't know why this is happening, because the func geraPdf exists in the main code, but the Ui doesn't "see" the func.
How can I make this work?
Thank you guys!

Btw I'm using Linux Mint 19.3

Comment: `geraPdf` is not part of `classGui.py` thats what the error suggest. You have different ways to encouter this. I would prefer to add `from __main__ import *` in `classGui.py` here.

Comment: @Thingamabobs you mean import the main in the classGui? like `from mainClass import geraPdf`  Because If is this, I tried and it does not work kkkk :(

Comment: @AndersonSilvestre, I guess you should add `from __main__ import *` at the top (with your `import`s), so the `geraPdf()` function is imported.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder so I add imported the main class in the classGui, but it gave me another error. So the file zpl_printer_test_object is my main code.

`File "zpl_printer_test_object.py", line 40, in <module>
    from classGui import ProgGui
  File "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/etiqueta/classGui.py", line 13, in <module>
    from zpl_printer_test_object import *
  File "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/etiqueta/zpl_printer_test_object.py", line 40, in <module>
    from classGui import ProgGui
ImportError: cannot import name 'ProgGui' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the circular import of `MainClass`'s contents in `classGui.py` and `classGui`'s `ProgGui` in `MainClass.py`. (Both the files are dependent on each other)

As both the files are importing each other's contents (functions like `geraPdf()` and classes like `ProgGui`) before they're initialized, you get the `ImportError`.

I've changed where they're `import`ed:

**`MainClass.py`:**

```py
from ctypes import cast
import requests
import shutil
import sys
import csv
import os
from tkinter import *

modelo_etiqueta_mm =[
    [20,35], [30,75], [50,105]
]

modelo_etiqueta_in =[
    [0.787402,1.37795], [1.1811,2.95276], [1.9685,4.13386]
]

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'base_produtos.csv')


def main_shell():
    pass

def ProgGui():
    pass

def cria_etiqueta(pos_coluna, pos_linha, produto, cod_barra):
    pass

def busca_produto(p_cod_produto):
    pass

def cria_linha(p_qtd_etiqueta,p_cod_produto, p_linhas):
    pass

def cria_zpl(p_cod_produto, p_qtd_etiqueta, p_modelo_etiqueta):
    pass

def geraPdf():
    pass

from classGui import ProgGui #moved it here, so the functions are initialized before they're imported/used

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(sys.argv)

    # separa a execução, se chamar com parametro é execução por shell
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2: # aqui fazes a verificacao sobre quantos args queres receber, o nome do programa conta como 1
        print('Execução de shell.')
        main_shell()
    else :
        print('Execução com Interface')
        gui = ProgGui()
        #gui.mainloop()

    # encerra execução
    sys.exit()
```

**`classGui.py`:**

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ProgGui:
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__()
        
        quantEtiquetas = IntVar()
        codInt = IntVar()
        
        master.title('Etiquetas')
        master.geometry('500x200')
        self.pad = ttk.Frame(app, padding=100)
        
        self.nomeProg = ttk.Label(app, text="Etiquetas").grid(sticky='E')
        self.etqTxt = ttk.Label(app, text="Cod do produto").grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.quanTxt = ttk.Label(app, text="Quant de etiquetas").grid(column=0, row=2)
        
        self.entryCod = ttk.Entry(app, textvariable=codInt).grid(column=1, row=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.entryqantEtiquetas = ttk.Entry(app, textvariable=quantEtiquetas).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=20, pady=20)
        
        self.btnQuit = ttk.Button(app, text="Quit", command=app.destroy).grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.btnPdf = ttk.Button(app, text="Gera Pdf", command=geraPdf).grid(column=0, row=3)

from MainClass import * #moved it here, so the ProgGui class is initialized before it's imported/used

app = Tk()
tela = ProgGui(app)
app.mainloop()
```

I've moved the `import`s after the necessary contents of the files are declared/defined/initialized and have also replaced the `#Code`s with `pass`es.

`MainClass.py` is your main file, and `classGui.py` has the main UI.

See [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59384553/16136190.

I've tested it, and it works for me.

Comment: Thank you :) This resolved the problem. I'm with another problem, in the variable codInt that the Entry gets it like a 'type' variable, not an Int (as it supposes to be). But I think I can handle it (and it's a problem for another question anyway). Again Thank You!