# ImportError: cannot import name 'RightsMaster' from partially initialized module 'DATABASE.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

from DATABASE.models import ModuleMaster, PageMaster, RightsMaster
ImportError: cannot import name 'RightsMaster' from partially initialized module 'DATABASE.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\python server\DATABASE\models_*init*_.py)

module_page.py

```
from django.db import models


class ModuleMaster(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    icon_class = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'module_master'


class PageMaster(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(ModuleMaster, models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'page_master'
```

rights_master.py

```
from django.db import models


class RightsMaster(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rights_master'
```

user_rights.py

```
from django.db import models
from DATABASE.models import ModuleMaster, PageMaster, RightsMaster

class UserRights(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    right = models.ForeignKey(RightsMaster, models.CASCADE)
    module = models.ForeignKey(ModuleMaster, models.CASCADE)
    page = models.ForeignKey(PageMaster, models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_rights'
```

**init**.py

```
from .profocus_py.module_page import ModuleMaster, PageMaster
from .profocus_py.user_rights import UserRights
from .profocus_py.rights_master import RightsMaster
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do circular imports seemingly work further up in the call stack but then raise an ImportError further down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/why-do-circular-imports-seemingly-work-further-up-in-the-call-stack-but-then-rai)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it

I was trying to import ModuleMaster in user_rights.py
But it is already connected with Foreign_key in PageMaster