# Python: cannot import name funct Error

Tags: python, python-import

So I have this directory structure:

```
proj/
|
---/subDirA
   |
   ---__init__.py
   ---fileA.py
|
---/subDirB
   |
   ---__init__.py
   ---fileB.py
|
---start.py
```

So what I'm trying to do is from fileB.py import a function in FileA.py. So I tried this:

```
from subDirA.fileA import funct
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name funct
```

But If I do this instead:

```
from subDirA.fileA import *
```

I dont get the error.. Can some one explain why am I getting this error?

I also tried the following without any success: (using absolute_import)

```
from .subDirA.fileA import funct
```

(The real function name is send_message())

**UPDATE**

Here are the real imports for better reference, in File A I have the following imports:

```
import pika
import logging
import tasks
import ConfigParser
```

and here I have a function def:

```
def send_message():
```

and in FileB I have:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from jsonpath_rw import parse
import dateutil.parser
import json
from pikahelper.rabbit import *  # Tried using send_message and it exploded, weird..

##
#  SubDirA/FileA.py => pikahelper/rabbit.py ;)
##
```

Also I'm calling start.py which also calls SubDirA/FileA.py for another function..

Comment: can you post some more information. I created a setup like this on my machine and it worked just fine. Is it possible that you have circular dependencies like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x ?

Comment: I verified this and I don't think I have any circular dependencies.. FileB calls FileA but FileA does not call FileB

Comment: but fileA is imported through start.py to begin with and you are calling start.py?

Comment: Actually yes I'm calling start.py and fileA is being imported through start.py.. could this be the problem ?

Comment: is SubDirA/__init__.py empty?

Comment: Yes it is.. It only has __author__