# Cannot import requests.packages.urllib3.util 'Retry'

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I am using Python 2.7 64 bit on Windows 8. I have Requests version 2.3 installed. I am trying to run this import statement as part of bringing in number of retries within my code:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import Retry
```

I have urllib3 installed also (I've just installed it now via Pip). I am getting the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\counter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.util import Retry
ImportError: cannot import name Retry
```

Can anyone tell me why this is? Are there any other dependencies I am unaware of to run this line of code successfully?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: Cannot import name X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: @alfasin I cant see anything on that page that will assist me?

Comment: Check your imports - it suggests that you have circular dependencies

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You might need a newer version of Requests. I just tried it with v2.5.1:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import Retry
```

Seems to work. FYI: The latest version is v2.5.3, worth upgrading.

Also if you have a reasonably recent version of urllib3 installed separately, this should also work:

```
from urllib3.util import Retry
```

Unfortunately we check the specific `isinstance` type of `Retry` in `PoolManager` and `ConnectionPool`, so the two types of `Retry` objects might not be perfectly interchangeable. (If anyone wants to fix this, I'd be +1 on a PR.)

For now, if you're intending on using the `Retry` object with the `requests` version of `urllib3`, you'll need to import it from there directly.

Comment: i forgot to post an answer for this. i tried importing retry directly from urllib3 when i installed it a couple of days ago and it worked fine. thanks for the response though.

Comment: @gdogg371 Ah good to know, thanks. It should be fine in some/many cases, but there may be edge cases where they're not perfectly interchangeable. Keep that in mind if you run into weird behaviour. :)

Comment: What's the minimum version? urllib3 1.7.1/requests 2.2.1 shows the error.

Answer (score 23):

requests no longer has vendored modules in request.package

you will need to reference urllib3 directly

```py
from urllib3.util import Retry
```