# Python import paramiko error "cannot import name util"

Tags: python, importerror, paramiko

I have installed the paramiko module. However, when I tried to import that module. I got the following error.

```
import paramiko
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-e77d47aa6e4a> in <module>()
----> 1 import paramiko

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py in <module>()
     28 
     29 
---> 30 from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
     31 from paramiko.client import SSHClient, MissingHostKeyPolicy, AutoAddPolicy, RejectPolicy, WarningPolicy
     32 from paramiko.auth_handler import AuthHandler

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 import paramiko
---> 32 from paramiko import util
     33 from paramiko.auth_handler import AuthHandler
     34 from paramiko.ssh_gss import GSSAuth

ImportError: cannot import name util
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which command did you use to install paramiko?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: Just checked on a Linux install, and /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py has the same line (but at 33).  This "cannot import name" error often relates to circularly dependent imports, but paramiko doesn't typically have that problem itself (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x for an example).  Which version of python?  Are you importing other things before your example?

Comment: Was this resolved? I'm having the same issue with python 2.7.6

Answer (score 2):

I have just had the same issue myself (python 2.7.6), and ran into this answer here
[ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x) , which was referred in the question's comments, suggesting it's a circular dependency issue.

After not finding any elegant solution I found myself editing paramiko's source code in `site-packages/paramiko/transport.py`:

- Comment / remove the line `from paramiko import util`
- Replace every occurrence of `util` (in this file) to `paramiko.util`
- Be careful while replacing: DO NOT replace existing occurrences of `paramiko.util`

This had fixed the problem for me, leaving me somewhat confused: on the one hand, modifying the import method seems to solve this, but on the other hand Python deals with it in like... 99% of the cases..? Awkward.

Answer (score 1):

We can just edit the import line to be:

```
from . import util
```

So we don't have to change every occurrence.

It is strange that after fixing this in paramiko 2.4, I have another import error, which is:

```
> python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 38, in <module>
    from paramiko.auth_handler import AuthHandler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 48, in <module>
    from paramiko.ssh_gss import GSSAuth, GSS_EXCEPTIONS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ssh_gss.py", line 54, in <module>
    GSS_EXCEPTIONS = (gssapi.GSSException,)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GSSException'
```

It turns out that I have somehow installed `cyrus-sasl-gssapi` which has the module `gssapi` but without `GSSException`. So python is confused. I removed the package and all is fine. If you have `python-gssapi`, be sure to remove that, too.

It is an issue of paramiko([#1069](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1069)). But not fixed in paramiko 2.4 for Python 2.7. Have reported it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with reinstalling it. In my case, it works.

```
pip uninstall paramiko
pip install paramiko --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

My method is Download python utils from here https://pypi.org/project/utils/#files，and pip install utils-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl， the problem has been resolved。I think the real cause is without the lib utils。

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Kludge's answer, we will need to replace "util" with paramiko.util" in each of the following files:
**transport.py, dsskey.py, ber.py, pkey.py, kex_gex.py, kex_group1.py, kex_gss.py, packet.py, primes.py, sftp_client.py, sftp.py, sftp_server.py.**

Quoting Kludge's method for better clarity:

- Comment / remove the line from paramiko import util
- Replace every occurrence of util (in this file) to paramiko.util
- Be careful while replacing: DO NOT replace existing occurrences of paramiko.util