# ImportError: cannot import name VarianceThreshold

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bigdata

scikit-learn seems to work, but when I did:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
```

I got the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name VarianceThreshold

How to bypass this? I am a newbie in Python, so I have no idea what to do.

I played with the order of my imports, as suggested here: [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x), but no luck.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn import decomposition
```

---

I am also getting this:

```
code/python/k_means/serial_version$ python -c 'import sklearn; print(sklearn.VarianceThreshold)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VarianceThreshold'
```

---

Version:

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.14.1'
```

Comment: Same issue here. What OS are you on?

Comment: @GeorgeWS I was on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bits at the time of posting.

Comment: Okay. This was working for me yesterday on Ubuntu 14.04.4, but not working now ssh'd into the same machine from Mac OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: @GeorgeWS I have absolutely no idea why you are facing problems. You could post a new question *or* if you think that mine can be extended, you should put a bounty on it and edit my question.

Comment: Totally—not expecting you to know what's causing it for me. Curious though, did you ever solve it on your machine?

Comment: There could be a chance I knew @GeorgeWS! Now that you are mentioning it, deadline was approaching fast for my project back then, so no, I moved forward. Probably this can still be an active question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass by catching the exception

```
try:
    from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
except:
    pass  # it will catch any exception here
```

If you want to catch only Attribue Error Exception then use below

```
try:
    from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
except AttributeError:
    pass # catches only Attribute Exception
```

Comment: So, there is no way I can *actually* use VarianceThreshold, right? :/

Comment: from documnetation you are importing module correctly. [link to document](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). you can try python -c 'import sklearn; print(sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold)'

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'feature_selection'`. OK thanks.