# Python Imports failing. Relative imports, package recognition, __init__.py , __package__, __all__

Tags: python, import, python-2.x

I've been reading a lot of threads, the PEP articles related to this problem, which are around 4 of them, but none of them gives a clear idea on some points and I still can't do relative imports.

In fact, the contents of my main package is not listed at all.

**REEDITION. I modified all the post, it was too complex and questions were a lot.**

In `C:/test/` I have this package:

```
Package/ (FOLDER 2)
    __init__.py
    moduleA.py
    moduleB.py
```

- `moduleA` imports `moduleB`, and viceversa.
- `__init__.py` is empty

My process:

1. I add `C:/test/` to `sys.path`.
2. `import Package`  (WORKS)
3. `dir(Package)`  **Doesn't list any module inside Package.**
4. Package is: `<module ‘Package’ from C:/test/Package/_init_.py>`
5. `__file__` is the init file under Package
6. `__name__` is `Package`
7. `__package__` **is an empty string**
8. `__path__` is `C:/test/Package`

---

TEST 1 - Version 1:
in `moduleA` I have `from Package import moduleB`

I get this:

```
>>> import Package.moduleA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/test\Package\moduleA.py", line
    from Package import moduleB
  File "C:/test\Package\moduleB.py", line
    from Package import moduleA
ImportError: cannot import name moduleA
```

*It doesn't work because `moduleA` is not part of `Package`. So `Package` is not recognized as a package?*

---

TEST 1 - Version 2:
in `moduleA` I have `from . import moduleB`

Doesn't work, same error

---

TEST 1 - Version 3: 
in `moduleA` I have `import Package.moduleB`

It works.

After that, running:

```
>>> dir(Package.moduleB)
['Package', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> Package.moduleB.Package
<module 'Package' from 'C:/prueba\Package\__init__.py'>
>>> dir(Package)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'moduleA', 'moduleB']
```

So now, `Package.moduleB`  has  `Package` as a variable 
And surprisingly, `Package` how looks like a proper package, and contains both modules.

In fact, doing any of imports in Version 1 and Version 2 work now, because now `moduleA` and `moduleB` are part of `Package`.

---

Questions:

1) Why is `Package` not recognized as a package? Is it? Shouldn't it contain all submodules?

2) Why running `import Package.moduleA`  generates `Package` inside `moduleA`?

3) Why running `import Package.moduleA` adds `moduleA` to `Package` and it wasn't there before?

4) Does an empty `__init__.py` file, and a NON empty `__init__.py` file affect to this at all?

5) Does defining an `__all__` variable containing `['moduleA', 'moduleB']` would do anything here?

6) How can I make the init file to load both submodules? Should I do `import Package.moduleA` and `Package.moduleB` inside?... can't I do it relatively like `import .moduleA as moduleA` or something like that? (What If the name of `Package` changes?)

7) Does that empty string on the package variable affect? We should change it's contents if we want it to recognize itself... `__package__` should be the same as `__name__`, or that's what the PEPs say. But doing this didn't work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "Package"
```

Comment: `import moduleB #inside moduleA doesn't work` -- what is the stack trace that you get? You are going to be getting problems since you are implying that `Package` in `test2` is a package (as it has an `__init__`), but you are giving adding to `C:/test2/Package` to the path instead of `C:/test2` (meaning it can't be a package). Are your modules in both folders called `moduleA` and `moduleB`. This is important as `test/Package/script.moduleA` could be importing `test2/Package/moduleB`.

Comment: @Dunes I edited the full post to make all questions clear. It was too convoluted and I saw I was confusing everybody.

Comment: Seems like your problem is that you have a circular dependency. Do `moduleA` and `moduleB` both import each other?

Comment: Yep. They do. I didn't know this problem could happen in python too...

Comment: Seems like my problem looks like this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/746655/772739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a circular dependency issue. It's very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x/23836838#23836838), but differs in that you are trying import a module from a package, rather than a class from a module. The best solution in this case is to rethink your code such that a circular dependency is not required. Move any common functions or classes out to a third module in the package.

Worrying about `__package__` is a red herring. The python import system will set this appropriately when your package becomes a proper package.

The problem is that `moduleA` and `moduleB` are only placed in `package` once they have been successfully imported. However, since both `moduleA` and `moduleB` are in the process of being imported they cannot see each other in `package`. The absolute import partially solves the problem as you bypass the relative import machinery. However, should your modules require parts of each other during initialisation then the program will fail.

The following code would work if the `var = ...` line was removed.

package.moduleA

```
import package.moduleB
def func():
    return 1
```

package.moduleB

```
import package.moduleA
var = package.moduleA.func() # error, can't find moduleA
```

#### Example of a *broken* package

package.moduleA

```
from . import moduleB
def depends_on_y():
    return moduleB.y()
def x():
    return "x"
```

package.moduleB

```
from . import moduleA
def depends_on_x():
    return moduleA.x()
def y():
    return "y"
```

#### Example of extracting common parts into separate module in package

package.common

```
def x():
    return "x"
def y():
    return "y"
```

package.moduleA

```
from .common import y
def depends_on_y():
    return y()
```

package.moduleB

```
from .common import x
def depends_on_x():
    return x()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python bug that exists in Python versions prior to 3.5. See [issue 992389](http://bugs.python.org/issue992389) where it was discussed (for many years) and [issue 17636](http://bugs.python.org/issue17636) where the common cases of the issue were fixed.

After the fix in Python 3.5, an explicit relative import like `from . import moduleA` from within a module within the package `Package` will check in `sys.modules` for `Package.moduleA` before giving up if `moduleA` isn't present yet in `Package`. Since the module object is added to `sys.modules` before it starts loading, but is not added to `Package.__dict__` until after the loading is complete, this usually fixes the problem.

There can still be a problem with circular imports using `from package import *`, but in [issue 23447](http://bugs.python.org/issue23447) (which I contributed a patch for), it was decided that fixing that even more obscure corner case was not worth the extra code complexity.

Circular imports are usually a sign of bad design. You should probably either refactor the bits of the code that depend on each other out into a single utility module that both of the other modules import, or you should combine both of the two separate modules into a single one.