# python : cannot import name JIRA

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I have already done `pip install jira`

but when I run the following it fails with ImportError: **cannot import name JIRA**

```
import re
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://issues.net')
# all values are samples and won't work in your code!
key_cert_data = None
key_cert_file = "cert/jiraprivatekey.pub"
with open(key_cert, 'r') as key_cert_file:
    key_cert_data = key_cert_file.read()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: Cannot import name X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 34):

fixed it.

The file I was running was called jira.py so when I did from

**jira import JIRA**

It was trying to look up self.

Comment: I'd like to note that you can turn on absolute import paths and keep your file named jira.py if it makes sense to you to do that

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave Can you explain how?

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey added an answer explaining how

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Organ note

> I'd like to note that you can turn on absolute import paths and keep
>   your file named jira.py if it makes sense to you to do that

In my case, I did this twice:

```
from jira import JIRA
jira = JIRA(URL_JIRA, basic_auth=('abc', '123'))
```

So in the first show, it's working good because `jira` is the global namespace but in second usage it doesn't because `jira` became just instance of JIRA.

This is my solution based on Organ's note:

```
import jira.client
x = jira.client.JIRA(URL_JIRA, basic_auth=('123', 'abc'))
```

Here, you can keep having jira.py and use these lines as much as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error when I installed python 3.6,earlier I had python 2.7. 
and jira was working.
I renamed the  python3.6 exe as python3 and python 2.7 exe as python,
issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

In my case `from jira import Jira` was resolved with next steps:

1. run in command line under (venv) :

```
pip install jira 
pip install 'jira[cli]'
```

or if you are not in (venv):

```
pip install jira 
python -m venv jira_python
source jira_python/bin/activate
pip install 'jira[cli]'
```

2. Add into block of imports of your *.py file:

```
from jira import JIRA
jira = JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com')
```

The official doc you will find here: 
https://jira.readthedocs.io/installation.html 
and here: 
https://pypi.org/project/jira/

Hope somebody it will helps.