# How to fix a circular import when inheriting from Scrapy's RetryMiddleware class?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to adapt Scrapy's [RetryMiddleware](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py) class, overriding the `_retry` method with a copy-pasted version in which I just add one additional line. I tried starting my custom middleware module as follows:

```
import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry
from scrapy.utils.python import global_object_name
```

However, this gives rise to an

> ImportError: cannot import name global_object_name

According to [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x), this type of error is caused by circular imports, but in this case I cannot easily remove dependencies in Scrapy's source code. How can I fix this?

For the sake of completeness, here is the `TorRetryMiddleware` I'm trying to implement:

```
import logging
import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry
from scrapy.utils.python import global_object_name
import apkmirror_scraper.tor_controller as tor_controller

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TorRetryMiddleware(scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        super(TorRetryMiddleware, self).__init__(settings)
        self.retry_http_codes = {403, 429}                  # Retry on 403 ('Forbidden') and 429 ('Too Many Requests')

    def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
        '''Same as original '_retry' method, but with a call to 'change_identity' before returning the Request.'''
        retries = request.meta.get('retry_times', 0) + 1

        stats = spider.crawler.stats
        if retries <= self.max_retry_times:
            logger.debug("Retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                         {'request': request, 'retries': retries, 'reason': reason},
                         extra={'spider': spider})
            retryreq = request.copy()
            retryreq.meta['retry_times'] = retries
            retryreq.dont_filter = True
            retryreq.priority = request.priority + self.priority_adjust

            if isinstance(reason, Exception):
                reason = global_object_name(reason.__class__)

            stats.inc_value('retry/count')
            stats.inc_value('retry/reason_count/%s' % reason)

            tor_controller.change_identity()    # This line is added to the original '_retry' method      

            return retryreq
        else:
            stats.inc_value('retry/max_reached')
            logger.debug("Gave up retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                         {'request': request, 'retries': retries, 'reason': reason},
                         extra={'spider': spider})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally don't think this `ImportError` comes from circular imports. Instead, it's highly likely that your version of Scrapy does not yet contain `scrapy.utils.python.global_object_name`.

`scrapy.utils.python.global_object_name` didn't come until [this commit](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/e285b1d6c2aaa1fdfe788f1894b0196bc64d1be1), which does not yet belong to any existing releases (the latest release is v1.3.3) (it's targeting to version v1.4, though).

Please verify that you *are* using the code from GitHub and your code does contain that very commit.

**EDITED:**

Regarding:

> According to ImportError: Cannot import name X, this type of error is caused by circular imports,

There are many reasons that may cause an `ImportError`. Usually the stack trace would be sufficient to determine the root cause. E.g.

```
>>> import no_such_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named no_such_name
```

While a circular import shall have quite different stack trace, e.g.

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS-Precision-7510 tmp]$ cat foo.py 
from bar import baz
baz = 1
[pengyu@GLaDOS-Precision-7510 tmp]$ cat bar.py 
from foo import baz
baz = 2
[pengyu@GLaDOS-Precision-7510 tmp]$ python -c "import foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bar import baz
  File "/tmp/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import baz
ImportError: cannot import name 'baz'
```