# Importing variables between scripts

Tags: python, import, sys

I am trying to move variables between scripts. I have two scripts: script1.py and script2.py

In script1.py I am using sys.argv to create a variable called country. 
This variable is imported to script2.py which process the country variable. The problem is when I try to import this new variable back to 
script1.py I get the following error:

```
from script2 import rule
ImportError: cannot import name 'rule'
```

I am running the script1.py in the terminal

```
python script1.py us
```

script1.py

```
import sys
country = str(sys.argv[1])
from script2 import rule
print (rule)
```

script2.py

```
from script1 import country
rule = 'this is a rule' + country
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: This is a case of circular dependent imports. Check out: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: Not sure this is 100% dupe.

Comment: You can generally avoid this issue by avoiding `from` imports (at least in your case). Access the members by `script1.country` and `script2.rule` and you should be fine. Also, avoid circular imports if you can. Not that you always can, but they always do complicate things.

Comment: I tried using  `script1.country` and `script2.rule`
and I get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'script2' has no attribute 'rule'`

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependent imports would raise ImportError.
Modify your scripts as follows:

script1.py

```
import sys
country = str(sys.argv[1])
from script2 import rule
print(rule(country))
```

script2.py (just one line)

```
rule = 'this is a rule{}'.format
```

Comment: But it worked on my machine.What's your OS and your python version?

Comment: using python 3.6. OS =  MacOS Sierra. Version 10.12.14

Comment: I have no idea now. I also use python 3.6, while OS = Ubuntu 17, and the scripts  worked as expected.