# Set a variable from a class within a different file

Tags: python-3.x, variables, import

I have 2 files:

> fileA.py

and

> fileB.py

I am trying to set (change) a variable from `fileA` from a function within `fileB`. The variable I'm trying to change is inside of a class (I believe the variable is a Class variable). I tried importing `fileA` inside of `fileB` but got errors.

```
# fileA:
...
class SomeDialog(QDialog):
    my_var = 0
...


# fileB:
...
from fileA import SomeDialog as sd
    def my_func():
        sd.my_var = 5
...
```

Any help?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'SomeDialog'

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you got, you probably have circular import somewhere. It is not related to what you are trying to do with your classes.

See [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x) for more details

If that's the case, the only way to solve it is to change your file structures.

Comment: Even if you're right (and you might be), it doesn't answer the question of how to change a class variable from another file. The answers here are for instance changes. I'm looking for an alternative way of doing this..

Comment: @Mr.Robot The method you are using appear to be right. I tested on my computer and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this:

```
class SomeDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_var = 0
```

Then you can access the `my_var` like this:

```
SomeDialog.my_var
```

Comment: This is a large program with thousands of lines. I have that variable used in lots of places and it is defined before init. BTW is your answer for an instance variable?

Comment: @Mr.Robot You could make it an instance variable

Comment: The thing is I can't. it is important that it stays as a class variable for the program. The value has to always be constant within the different instances. I'm looking for an answer for the way it is shown above.

Comment: Ok, sorry then, I cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

Class variables are defined within a class but outside any of the class's methods. Class variables are not used. class variables have the same value across all class instances

**A.py**

```
from B import SomeDialog as sd
def my_func():
    print sd.my_var
    sd.my_var = 5
    return sd 
_my_func = my_func()
print _my_func.my_var
```

**B.py**

```
class SomeDialog(object):
    my_var = 0
```

**#output**

```
0
5
```