# Switch between two frames in tkinter using a separate file for each page

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import

I've created a tkinter app, which has three pages: StartPage, PageOne and PageTwo. From StartPage you can go to PageOne and to PageTwo, whereas from PageOne and PageTwo, you can go back to StartPage. To implement it, I am using the technique described by Steven Vascellaro in this post [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028).

This is the code provided by Steven:

```
# Multi-frame tkinter application v2.2
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        start_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page")
        page_1_button = tk.Button(self, text="Open page one",
                                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne))
        page_2_button = tk.Button(self, text="Open page two",
                                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo))
        start_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        page_1_button.pack()
        page_2_button.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        page_1_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one")
        start_button = tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                                 command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage))
        page_1_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        start_button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        page_2_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page two")
        start_button = tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                                 command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage))
        page_2_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        start_button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Now, I am trying to make this code modular and place each page in a separate python file. This is how I split the Steven's code between three Python files (start_page.py, page_one.py, page_two.py):

start_page.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from page_one import PageOne
from page_two import PageTwo


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        start_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page")
        page_1_button = tk.Button(self, text="Open page one",
                                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne))
        page_2_button = tk.Button(self, text="Open page two",
                                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo))
        start_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        page_1_button.pack()
        page_2_button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

page_one.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from start_page import StartPage

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        page_1_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one")
        start_button = tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                                 command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage))
        page_1_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        start_button.pack()
```

page_two.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from start_page import StartPage

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        page_2_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page two")
        start_button = tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                                 command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage))
        page_2_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        start_button.pack()
```

The problem is here the class StartPage depends on PageOne and PageTwo, while PageOne and PageTwo depend on StartPage. This leads to the error described in this post [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x).

Is there a way in tkinter to keep the described functionality, but to allow each page to be located in a separate python file?

Comment: post the code to get assistance.

Comment: In the example in the post you linked, the pages have no reference to each other. There should be no problem putting them in separate files and importing all of them in the file with the controller (SampleApp).

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: Yeah, I have just used the code with the controller and it works fine now.

Comment: No, I was not using the code that uses the class name. I was using the one proposed by Bryan Oakley, which is not the most voted answer there.