# text summarization using Text-Summarizer in python

Tags: python, text, summarization

I am trying to use below library which is available in website

https://pypi.org/project/text-summarizer/

from text_summarizer import summarizer

As informed in website i have installed text_summarizer package using below syntax below when loading it in python i am getting error
ImportError: cannot import name 'summarizer'

Can anyone help me if this package is working

Comment: Did you name your own file `text_summarizer.py`?

Comment: @BryanOakley, no I tried to run script which mentioned in web site post installation of package text_summarizer , but first line throwing error " ImportError: cannot import name 'summarizer'"

Comment: @user, to debug your problem try this and let us know what it says: `import text_summarizer; print(dir(text_summarizer))`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a circular dependencies import. This might just be the same answer as this question here: [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re
import nltk

impfile = ""

number_of_sentences_in_summary = 7
max_words_in_sentence = 20


import sys, getopt

## From https://stackabuse.com/text-summarization-with-nltk-in-python/
## NLTK install instructions are at https://www.nltk.org/

number_of_sentences_in_summary = int(sys.argv[1])
max_words_in_sentence = int(sys.argv[2])
scraped_data = urllib.request.urlopen(sys.argv[3])
scraped_data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence')
article = scraped_data.read()

parsed_article = bs.BeautifulSoup(article,'lxml')

paragraphs = parsed_article.find_all('p')

article_text = ""

for p in paragraphs:
    article_text += p.text


# Removing Square Brackets and Extra Spaces
article_text = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]*\]', ' ', article_text)
article_text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', article_text)


# Removing special characters and digits
formatted_article_text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', article_text )
formatted_article_text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', formatted_article_text)

sentence_list = nltk.sent_tokenize(article_text)


stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
#stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('hungarian')

word_frequencies = {}
for word in nltk.word_tokenize(formatted_article_text):
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word not in word_frequencies.keys():
            word_frequencies[word] = 1
        else:
            word_frequencies[word] += 1

maximum_frequncy = max(word_frequencies.values())

for word in word_frequencies.keys():
    word_frequencies[word] = (word_frequencies[word]/maximum_frequncy)


sentence_scores = {}
for sent in sentence_list:
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent.lower()):
        if word in word_frequencies.keys():
            if len(sent.split(' ')) < max_words_in_sentence:
                if sent not in sentence_scores.keys():
                    sentence_scores[sent] = word_frequencies[word]
                else:
                    sentence_scores[sent] += word_frequencies[word]



import heapq
summary_sentences = heapq.nlargest(number_of_sentences_in_summary, sentence_scores, key=sentence_scores.get)

summary = '\n'.join(summary_sentences)
print(summary)
```

Comment: How is your question addressing the import problem?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**