# ImportError: cannot import name 'pareto'

Tags: python-3.x

This import command  `from paretochart import pareto` gives error `ImportError:` `cannot import name 'pareto`'.

Paretochart installed via terminal by this coomand: `conda install paretochart /pip install paretochart`. Anybody know any other methods or any suggestions for get rid of this error?

PLatform: Spyder

Comment: Try `pip3 install paretochart`

Comment: still same error..

Comment: Module seems to be found, maybe it's an loop import error (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x))