# Import error while trying to import a variable within a function in another python script

Tags: python, django

I have created a function in *views.py* which is

```
def func(request)
    # …
```

Basically, I tried using the variable var, in another python file, say *z.py*, by typing:

```
from views import func
```

but I got the error

> ImportError: cannot import name func.

Please help me out. I want to use the variable var in the other python script, but am getting this error.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: directory structure? it should be `from appname.views import func`

Comment: yeah I did that. But still it's showing Import error.

Comment: I did from nameofmyapp.views import func, but it is throwing this Import error.

Comment: your directory structure? add that. Hope you are not making [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x) mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you have a `__init__.py` file under the directory appname.