# Where is this ImportError coming from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I developed a new module and want to integrate it in an existing package (coming from a Git repository). However, I can't import the module newly created. Does anyone know why?

config: python3.6\ IDE: VS2017, Spyder

Structure:

```
repoA/__init__.py
repoA/repoB/
repoA/repoB/__init__.py
repoA/repoB/moduleA.py
repoA/repoB/moduleB.py <= added module
```

test Code located in another repository

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r"..\tatata\tututu")
Import repoA.repoB
from repoA.repoB import moduleA
from repoA.repoB import moduleB
```

moduleA

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
```

moduleB

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Radiobutton, IntVar, filedialog
```

result:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'moduleB'
```

Apparently, the ModuleA is found but not the moduleB and I dont understand why as they are located in the same Directory.
Do I need to touch the `__init__.py` ?
(previously, the moduleB was having a class named moduleB. I changed the name of the class without any effect on the error)

Comment: In which file your test code is?

Comment: What do `moduleA` and `moduleB` import? If `A` imports `B` and `B` imports `A` it won't be able to resolve the import.

Comment: `reposB` `!=` `repoB`

Comment: I edited the Question to give more details. Thanks to both of you

Comment: After importing `moduleA`, do `print(moduleA.__file__)`. Does the path to `moduleA` correspond to the location of `moduleB.py`?

Comment: There is already a useful link about circular dependancies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x

Refer to the answer from "Dunes".

Answer (score 0):

@ShadowRanger: Man! you got it. The whole structure was in fact existing twice in this project (repoA/repoB/moduleA was in repoC/ and repoC/repoD/   !!!) ._.  I will clean that and then it should work. 
Many thanks to all of you !