# Why i cant run my script, problems with modules

Tags: python, anaconda, instagram

**I can't run script because of this problem**

It's frequent problem for me, but now i don't know what to do.

```
(base) C:\Users\Mimek\Desktop\instagram-followers-scraper-master>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from modules import compare
ImportError: cannot import name 'compare' from 'modules' (C:\Users\Mimek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\modules.py)
```

but

```
(base) C:\Users\Mimek\Desktop\instagram-followers-scraper-master>pip install modules
Requirement already satisfied: modules in c:\users\mimek\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)

(base) C:\Users\Mimek\Desktop\instagram-followers-scraper-master>pip install compare
Requirement already satisfied: compare in c:\users\mimek\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.2b0)
```

I already installed these modules.

Please help me guys I cant stand it anymore -_-

Comment: But... according to `pip`, `modules` and `compare` are different modules. Why are you trying to import one from the other?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime
from modules import compare
from modules import file_io
from modules import stats

from modules.scraper import Scraper
from modules.utils import ask_input, ask_multiple_option`

Comment: It's not my code, i got it from github, just needed instagram scraper

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/tonoli/instagram-followers-scraper)? If so, have you followed the instructions in the README?

Comment: Exactly, i did everything

Comment: Why did you do `pip install modules` and `pip install compare`, then? The README doesn't say anything about that. In fact, `modules` is a directory that's already provided by the repo, along with `modules.compare`, `modules.stats` and the like. You should uninstall `modules` and `compare` that you installed via `pip` - they have nothing to do with this project.

Comment: You're completely right, i just deleted modules.py from site-packages and everything is working. Thanks

Comment: Ugh, i got another error, `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210990/discussion-between-yoshow2137-and-forcebru).

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding first an `import modules` command. I think you have a dependency circle as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x).

Running a script as a module requires some carefulness in the way you handle dependencies.