# Circular dependencies in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have read several more questions on stackoverflow, but still don't understand.

From an example in another question, I created 2 simple modules that call each other to understand the circular import in python, but this has only generated more confusion for me.

I have the following 2 modules:

```
# module X.py

print('x1')
def X1():
    return "x1"

from Y import Y2
print('x2')
def X2():
    return "x2"
```

```
# module Y.py

print('y1')
def Y1():
    return "y1"
from X import X1

print('y2')
def Y2():
    return "y2"
```

When I run X.py an error happens:

```
x1
y1
x1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Y import Y2
  File "***/Y.py", line 6, in <module>
    from X import X1
  File "***/X.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Y import Y2
ImportError: cannot import name 'Y2' from 'Y' (***/Y.py)
```

When I run Y.py, no error happens, but I don't understand the order of the print.

```
y1
x1
y1
y2
x2
y2
```

I use python 3.8.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: Although I understand what they answer, it does not agree with what happens to me. When I run X I should run the X code and print 'x1', then I do 'from Y import Y2' so I should run Y and print 'y1', then with 'from X import X1' as X1 was already defined there should be no error, and then 'y2' should be printed, exit module Y and continue on X and print 'x2'.

But this is not what happens for me. Maybe I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Note that in your traceback `X.py` appears with and without its directory.  The outer one is a script, while the inner one is a module (albeit loaded from the same file!).

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/13782669) may help to realize importing process.

I tried to show the sequence of steps while importing in both cases below.

When you run `Y.py`. the order is:

- Running `Y.py` as `__main__`
- `def Y1()` -> define `Y1()` in `__main__`
- `from X import X1` -> import and run `X.py` as `X`
- `def X1()` -> define `X1()` in `X`
- `from Y import Y2` -> import and run `Y.py` as `Y`
- `def Y1()` -> define `Y1()` in `Y`
- `from X import X1` -> **OK**. `X.X1` **was defined already**
- `def Y2()` -> define `Y2()` in `Y`
- `def X2()` -> define `X2()` in `X`

And when you run `X.py`, the order is:

- Running `X.py` as `__main__`
- `def X1()` -> define `X1()` in `__main__`
- `from Y import Y2` -> import and run `Y.py` as `Y`
- `def Y1()` -> define `Y1()` in `Y`
- `from X import X1` -> import and run `X.py` as `X`
- `def X1()` -> define `X1()` in `X`
- `from Y import Y2` -> **ERROR**. `Y.Y2` **was not defined yet**

Comment: This is a great answer! The important thing is that when I run 'X.py' it runs as `__main__` and not as `X`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you run X.py, it attempts to import `Y2` from Y.py. In Y.py, `Y2` is defined *after* `from X import X1`, which causes the circular dependency.

When you run Y.py, it attempts to import `X1` from X.py. In X.py, `X1` is defined *before* `from Y import Y2`, so there is *no* circular dependency.