# receiving ImportError: cannot import name x from y

Tags: python

I am refactoring/moving some code in my init file for better readability and to manage my app's main file. As a result, I'm attempting to import a function from the refactor file into init, but I continue to get this error,

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'test_state_locations' from 'app.refactor'
```

Here is how I am importing:

```
# File: __init__.py

from .refactor import test_state_locations
```

```
# File: refactor.py

import requests
from privateinfo import key
from .__init__ import API_BASE_URL

def test_state_locations(state):
    url = f'https://covid-19-testing.github.io/locations/{state.lower()}/complete.json'
    res = requests.get(url)
    testing_data = res.json()
    latsLngs = {}
    for obj in testing_data:
          if obj["physical_address"]:

            for o in obj["physical_address"]:
                    addy = o["address_1"] 
                    city = o["city"]
                    phone = obj["phones"][0]["number"]

            location = f'{addy} {city}'
            res2 = requests.get(API_BASE_URL,
                                params={'key': key, 'location': location})

            location_coordinates = res2.json()
            lat = location_coordinates["results"][0]["locations"][0]["latLng"]["lat"]
            lng = location_coordinates["results"][0]["locations"][0]["latLng"]["lng"]
            latsLngs[location] = {'lat': lat, 'lng': lng, 'place': location, 'phone': phone}
```

Here is a photo of my app's directory:
[image]

Comment: @AvenDesta no. The dot implies that it is a relative import. the code, "./" throws a syntax error.

Comment: It is still throwing a syntax error.

Comment: u r right. I'm trying it on my PC. I'll let you know if I find a way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `refactor.py` import something from `__init__.py`; It makes `circular import issue`.

```py
#from .__init__ import API_BASE_URL
```

Comment: Nice observation.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a circular import.
In `__init__.py`, you're importing `refactor` and
circularly in `refactor.py` you're using `__init__`

Here is how python deals with your code. It first looks at `refactor.py` and tries to import `__init__`. But to import `__init__`, python has to run the file `__init__.py`. But again `__init__.py` requires `refactor`, and has to go back to `refactor.py`. At this point python stops the loop and raises `Import Error`.

Python import breaks if your import is circular. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x) for more.

If you're working with Flask framework, here is a [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44PvX0Yv368&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=5&t=120) tutorial to help you structure your modules to avoid circular import