# ImportError from tests directory in Python

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have the following project structure:

```
python_project
├── module
│   ├── constants.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script.py
└── tests
    ├── constants.py
    └── __init__.py
```

`python_project` is in `PYTHONPATH`.

```
module/constants.py:

VAR_MODULE = 25

tests/constants.py:

VAR = 17
```

I'm facing the following issue in `script.py` file:

```
from module.constants import VAR_MODULE
```

works

```
from tests.constants import VAR
```

throws the following exception:

```
    from tests.constants import VAR
ImportError: cannot import name 'VAR'
```

I know that there is no point in importing stuff from `tests` directory, just wondering why this does not work. Is `tests` directory excluded somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252628/8868327) helps ?

Comment: Yea, I was thinking the same (circular imports) (without seeing the full headers of both constants.py files

Comment: nope, see my update above

Comment: it is confused by tests directory

Comment: What if you do `from python_project.tests.constants import VAR`? Also let's check which `tests` this is. I suggest a simple `import tests` and `print(tests.__file__)`