# How can I fix a very basic ImportError in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

Similar to [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x), I have a main.py file and, in the same folder, a few other python files bill.py and flatmate.py.
bill.py and flatmate.py each contain classes, nothing more.

Directory structure:

```
parentfolder
- main.py
- bill.py
- flatmate.py
- files
  - pic.png
  - doc.pdf
```

Sample code:

main.py:

```
import bill                     # won't work
from flatmate import Flatmate   # won't work
...
```

bill.py:

```
class Bill:
    def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
```

flatmate.py:

```
class Flatmate:
    def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
```

I get an ImportError: cannot import name 'Bill' from 'bill' (c:\Users\lavid\Desktop\Python Experimente\Python OOP Kurs\App-2-Flatmates-Bill\bill.py). I am pretty sure I don't have circular references. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: what is your directory structure? How are you calling the module? As you have described, there should not be any problem in the import part.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all files are next each others
try:

```py
from . import module
```

if this doesn't work , add your files dir to the Question

Answer (score 0):

Saving the referenced files before accessing them helped a lot.