# from setuptools.errors import OptionError ImportError: cannot import name 'OptionError' from 'setuptools.errors'

Tags: python, setuptools, cx-freeze

i am trying to create an executable using cx_freeze. and when i run
`python setup.py build` i get the following error:

```
from setuptools.errors import OptionError
    ImportError: cannot import name 'OptionError' from 'setuptools.errors'
```

I am working in anaconda. I tried reverting to a previous cx_freeze version with no luck.
This a a new problem two month ago when i created another virtual envieonment i didn't have this problem. This is why i'm guessing it could be maybe a version issue. However i can't seem to  find the correct version to install.
i also checked other related issues however i didn't find a solution that works for me. If you have an idea please let me know!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without additional info, package versions, a more complete trace, etc.

I ran into this same error during a build post-upgrade of `cx_Freeze` but *after* already having `setuptools` installed. Reinstalling `setuptools` to the most current version (65.6.3) corrected the error in my case. I'm running `cx_Freeze` version 6.13.1 if it helps move you past the error.

Typically, Python errors of the sort `ImportError: cannot import name ...` indicate circular dependencies, e.g.,: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252628/9975319 - it could be that the order of imports `cx_Freeze` does changes across builds causing the dependencies to import incorrectly but I haven't dug deeper into it.