# ImportError: cannot import name '_adapters' from partially initializer module importlib_metadata' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, importerror, twine

I was updating my Pypi package using:

`python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

Then, running:

`python -m twine upload --https://github.com/ERijck/FuzzyTM https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`

Returned the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\Emil\surfdrive\PhD\3. Python Scripts\GitHub\FuzzyTM>python -m twine upload --https://github.com/ERijck/FuzzyTM https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\twine\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _adapters, _meta
ImportError: cannot import name '_adapters' from partially initialized module 'importlib_metadata' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py)
```

Based on the error and on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790289/importerror-cannot-import-name-idkom-from-partially-initialized-module-idkom) it seems that I have a circular import. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not a circular input. Having an older version of importlib_metadata installed caused the issue.

`pip install -U importlib_metadata` solved it.