# Error when importing locale lib in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, locale

I want to import T_FMT_AMPM from locale lib. But I got error, and that is:

```
from locale import T_FMT
ImportError: cannot import name 'T_FMT' from 'locale'
```

So what can I do now? Can u help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have circular import references - The thread below explains a bit more

[What can I do about "ImportError: Cannot import name X" or "AttributeError: ... (most likely due to a circular import)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/what-can-i-do-about-importerror-cannot-import-name-x-or-attributeerror)

You could try refactoring, or one of the other methods mentioned in the thread above