# Python bug - I randomly (seldom) get this strange error in GAE

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine

We have a package named model

In model, we have a TopicM module that defines a class Topic
We import it in a module named GeneralM in the same package.
Sometimes (rarely) we get this error:

What could be the cause?
Could it be circular imports?
Should we perhaps put something in `'__init__.py'?`

Please advise.

(I apologize for the lengthy error)
    --> --> -->

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> Python 2.7.2: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
Fri Jun 08 11:23:46 2012

A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _HandleRequest(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>)
   2779         outfile = cStringIO.StringIO()
   2780         try:
=> 2781           self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
   2782         finally:
   2783           self.module_manager.UpdateModuleFileModificationTimes()
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>, self._Dispatch = <bound method DevAppServerRequestHandler._Dispat...v_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>>, dispatcher = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object>, self.rfile = <socket._fileobject object>, outfile = <cStringIO.StringO object>, env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'F1F836CB', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance>, dispatcher=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object>, socket_infile=<socket._fileobject object>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'F1F836CB', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...})
   2667           dispatcher.Dispatch(app_server_request,
   2668                               outfile,
=> 2669                               base_env_dict=env_dict)
   2670         finally:
   2671           request_file.close()
base_env_dict undefined, env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'F1F836CB', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object>, request=<AppServerRequest relative_url: /prof?lectureKey...mp', mode 'rb' at 0x0384A860> force_admin: False>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, base_env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'F1F836CB', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...})
    690         forward_request = dispatcher.Dispatch(request,
    691                                               outfile,
=>  692                                               base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
    693 
    694         if forward_request:
base_env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'F1F836CB', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.CGIDispatcher object>, request=<AppServerRequest relative_url: /prof?lectureKey...mp', mode 'rb' at 0x0384A860> force_admin: False>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, base_env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'F1F836CB', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...})
   1729                      memory_file,
   1730                      outfile,
=> 1731                      self._module_dict)
   1732     finally:
   1733       logging.root.level = before_level
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.CGIDispatcher object>, self._module_dict = {'Cookie': <module 'Cookie' from 'C:\Python27\lib\Cookie.pyc'>, 'StringIO': <module 'StringIO' from 'C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.pyc'>, 'UserDict': <module 'UserDict' from 'C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.pyc'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__future__': <module '__future__' from 'C:\Python27\lib\__future__.pyc'>, '__main__': <module 'prof' from 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py'>, '_abcoll': <module '_abcoll' from 'C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.pyc'>, '_bisect': <module '_bisect' (built-in)>, '_collections': <module '_collections' (built-in)>, '_functools': <module '_functools' (built-in)>, ...}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in ExecuteCGI(config=<AppInfoExternal error_handlers=None b...one api_version=1 api_config=None >, root_path=r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src', handler_path='prof.py', cgi_path=r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py', env={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~greatest-app-ever', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', ...}, infile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object>, module_dict={'Cookie': <module 'Cookie' from 'C:\Python27\lib\Cookie.pyc'>, 'StringIO': <module 'StringIO' from 'C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.pyc'>, 'UserDict': <module 'UserDict' from 'C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.pyc'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__future__': <module '__future__' from 'C:\Python27\lib\__future__.pyc'>, '__main__': <module 'prof' from 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py'>, '_abcoll': <module '_abcoll' from 'C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.pyc'>, '_bisect': <module '_bisect' (built-in)>, '_collections': <module '_collections' (built-in)>, '_functools': <module '_functools' (built-in)>, ...}, exec_script=<function ExecuteOrImportScript>, exec_py27_handler=<function ExecutePy27Handler>)
   1629         reset_modules = exec_py27_handler(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
   1630       else:
=> 1631         reset_modules = exec_script(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
   1632     except SystemExit, e:
   1633       logging.debug('CGI exited with status: %s', e)
reset_modules = True, exec_script = <function ExecuteOrImportScript>, config = <AppInfoExternal error_handlers=None b...one api_version=1 api_config=None >, handler_path = 'prof.py', cgi_path = r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py', hook = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in ExecuteOrImportScript(config=<AppInfoExternal error_handlers=None b...one api_version=1 api_config=None >, handler_path='prof.py', cgi_path=r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py', import_hook=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>)
   1317 
   1318     if module_code:
=> 1319       exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
   1320     else:
   1321       script_module.main()
module_code = <code object <module> at 03760E78, file "C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py", line 2>, script_module = <module 'prof' from 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py'>, script_module.__dict__ = {'__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>, 'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>, 'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, 'BaseException': <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, 'BufferError': <type 'exceptions.BufferError'>, 'BytesWarning': <type 'exceptions.BytesWarning'>, 'DeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.DeprecationWarning'>, 'EOFError': <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>, 'Ellipsis': Ellipsis, 'EnvironmentError': <type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>, ...}, '__doc__': None, '__file__': r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py', '__loader__': <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, '__name__': 'prof', '__package__': None, 'run_wsgi_app': <function run_wsgi_app>, 'template': <module 'google.appengine.ext.webapp.template' f...engine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.pyc'>, 'webapp': <module 'google.appengine.ext.webapp' from 'D:\P...engine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.pyc'>}
 C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\prof.py in ()
      3 from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
      4 from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
=>    5 from model import TopicM
      6 from model import LectureM
      7 from model import GeneralM
model undefined, TopicM undefined
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in Decorate(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, *args=('model.TopicM',), **kwargs={})
    674     self._indent_level += 1
    675     try:
=>  676       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    677     finally:
    678       self._indent_level -= 1
func = <function load_module>, self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, args = ('model.TopicM',), kwargs = {}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in load_module(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, fullname='model.TopicM')
   1856         search_path = parent_module.__path__
   1857 
=> 1858     return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
   1859 
   1860   @Trace
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, self.FindAndLoadModule = <bound method HardenedModulesHook.Decorate of <g...ppserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>>, submodule = 'TopicM', fullname = 'model.TopicM', search_path = [r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model']
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in Decorate(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, *args=('TopicM', 'model.TopicM', [r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model']), **kwargs={})
    674     self._indent_level += 1
    675     try:
=>  676       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    677     finally:
    678       self._indent_level -= 1
func = <function FindAndLoadModule>, self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, args = ('TopicM', 'model.TopicM', [r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model']), kwargs = {}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in FindAndLoadModule(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, submodule='TopicM', submodule_fullname='model.TopicM', search_path=[r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model'])
   1720                                          source_file,
   1721                                          pathname,
=> 1722                                          description)
   1723 
   1724 
description = ('.py', 'U', 1)
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in Decorate(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, *args=('model.TopicM', <closed file 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py', mode 'U'>, r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py', ('.py', 'U', 1)), **kwargs={})
    674     self._indent_level += 1
    675     try:
=>  676       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    677     finally:
    678       self._indent_level -= 1
func = <function LoadModuleRestricted>, self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, args = ('model.TopicM', <closed file 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py', mode 'U'>, r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py', ('.py', 'U', 1)), kwargs = {}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in LoadModuleRestricted(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, submodule_fullname='model.TopicM', source_file=<closed file 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py', mode 'U'>, pathname=r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py', description=('.py', 'U', 1))
   1663                                      source_file,
   1664                                      pathname,
=> 1665                                      description)
   1666       except:
   1667 
description = ('.py', 'U', 1)
 C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\TopicM.py in ()
      2 from google.appengine.ext import db
=>    3 import GeneralM
      4 import LectureM
      5 
      6 def getTopicsByLecture(lecture):
GeneralM undefined
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in Decorate(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, *args=('model.GeneralM',), **kwargs={})
    674     self._indent_level += 1
    675     try:
=>  676       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    677     finally:
    678       self._indent_level -= 1
func = <function load_module>, self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, args = ('model.GeneralM',), kwargs = {}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in load_module(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, fullname='model.GeneralM')
   1856         search_path = parent_module.__path__
   1857 
=> 1858     return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
   1859 
   1860   @Trace
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, self.FindAndLoadModule = <bound method HardenedModulesHook.Decorate of <g...ppserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>>, submodule = 'GeneralM', fullname = 'model.GeneralM', search_path = [r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model']
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in Decorate(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, *args=('GeneralM', 'model.GeneralM', [r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model']), **kwargs={})
    674     self._indent_level += 1
    675     try:
=>  676       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    677     finally:
    678       self._indent_level -= 1
func = <function FindAndLoadModule>, self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, args = ('GeneralM', 'model.GeneralM', [r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model']), kwargs = {}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in FindAndLoadModule(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, submodule='GeneralM', submodule_fullname='model.GeneralM', search_path=[r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model', r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model'])
   1720                                          source_file,
   1721                                          pathname,
=> 1722                                          description)
   1723 
   1724 
description = ('.py', 'U', 1)
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in Decorate(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, *args=('model.GeneralM', <closed file 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py', mode 'U'>, r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py', ('.py', 'U', 1)), **kwargs={})
    674     self._indent_level += 1
    675     try:
=>  676       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    677     finally:
    678       self._indent_level -= 1
func = <function LoadModuleRestricted>, self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, args = ('model.GeneralM', <closed file 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py', mode 'U'>, r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py', ('.py', 'U', 1)), kwargs = {}
 D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py in LoadModuleRestricted(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object>, submodule_fullname='model.GeneralM', source_file=<closed file 'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py', mode 'U'>, pathname=r'C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py', description=('.py', 'U', 1))
   1663                                      source_file,
   1664                                      pathname,
=> 1665                                      description)
   1666       except:
   1667 
description = ('.py', 'U', 1)
 C:\Current Project\study-wise\src\model\GeneralM.py in ()
      2 from google.appengine.ext import db
      3 from google.appengine.api import users
=>    4 from TopicM import Topic
      5 from LectureM import Lecture
      6 
TopicM undefined, Topic undefined

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name Topic
      args = ('cannot import name Topic',)
      message = 'cannot import name Topic'
```

Comment: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving all possible imports to the bottom of the module,
If you planned your classes relations properly that should solve your problem!

Read this awesome answer if your problem refuse to vanish:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/894885/988434

Have fun hacking!

Answer (score 3):

See [Pythonic way to resolve circular import statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748946/pythonic-way-to-resolve-circular-import-statements). Based on this, change your import in GeneralM from `from TopicM import Topic` to just `import TopicM`, and then just qualify the references to `Topic` as `TopicM.Topic`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from model.TopicM import Topic
```

Try that.