# python import methods: working only in ipython

Tags: python, import, module, scipy, ipython

I am new to python and I am running into some troubles importing modules. I have very limited prior knowledge to programming (bit of Fortran and C) and I usually work with Matlab.

I searched the web for import methods and the preferred method according to most tutorials is: import X

If I use the console (iPython respectively) I can execute the following:

```
import scipy
scipy.stats.cauchy.pdf
```

However when I use the same line in a function it does not work, I have to use

```
import scipy.stats as s
s.stats.cauchy.pdf
```

or I get: *AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stats'*

By reading this ['import module' or 'from module import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import) I got the impression that both should work.

If someone could quickly clear that up for me I would be very thankful!

Best Wishes,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not happen on a *newly opened* `ipython` instance.  You would not normally be able to access like this:

```
import scipy 
scipy.stats.cauchy.pdf
```

Without getting `AttributeError`, in either `ipython` or regular `python` interpreter.  You would need to do

```
import scipy.stats
```

somewhere, because it is a submodule.

Either you have an earlier imported `scipy.stats` hanging around in your `ipython` namespace, or you have some automatic startup script importing it when `ipython` starts.

*Note:*  if you are using ipython's `run` magic function to execute a script, any global variables and imported modules will remain in scope.