# Process facebook messenger url image

Tags: image, python-2.7, flask, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to process this image provided by messenger-platform API (send-api-reference)

I used:
    url = "https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20916840_10214193209010537_198030613_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=3eab9a3a400c7e05fb5b74c391852426&oe=5998B9A8"

```
@app.route('/photobot/<path:photo_url>')
def tensor_photobot(photo_url):
  file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(photo_url).read())
  img = Image.open(file)

  if img:
    list_elements = process_image(img)
    return json.dumps(list_elements)
```

But the image is not recognized. Any idea?

Message:

> {u'mid': u'mid.$cAAbv-uhIfdVkIn9OVld8TqA6u2Hz', u'seq': 40125,
>   u'attachments': [{u'type': u'image', u'payload': {u'url':
>   u'https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20916840_10214193209010537_198030613_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=3eab9a3a400c7e05fb5b74c391852426&oe=5998B9A8'}}]}
>
> [Reference][1] python 2.x
>
> [1]:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/image-attachment

**Edit:** following comment recommendations, I detected the problem is from url-string truncation.

I added all the implementation for more context.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: IOError: cannot identify image file <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x11d019250>

Comment: How are you importing Image? It seems to be a common error where either  the user isn't using Pillow, or isn't importing with `from PIL import Image` vs `import Image` See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230991/image-open-cannot-identify-image-file-python).

Comment: I'm using from PIL import Image. The process works perfectly If I use another's image-urls, but not for the facebook-messenger attachment- images urls.

Comment: Any chance your code is truncating the query string when it's extracting it from the api response? I'm able to run this code fine, so trying to think of possible variances.

Comment: yes, that's the problem. Let me add all the implementation.

Comment: Great! I've added this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment in case the answer is needed by anyone in the future:

The query string is being truncated from the URL. To load the image, the entire URL including the query string is required.