# How do i read image using PILLOW image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I wanted read a image using PIL.Image.open().But I've image in different path.
The following is the path I've the python script

```
"D:\YY_Aadhi\holy-edge-master\hed\test.py"
```

The following is the path I've the image file.

```
"D:\YY_Aadhi\HED-BSDS\test\2018.jpg"

from PIL import Image
'''some code here'''
image = Image.open(????)
```

How should I fill the question mark to access the image file.

Comment: Did you really not just try `Image.open("D:\YY_Aadhi\HED-BSDS\test\2018.jpg")`?

Comment: So have you tried just fill path?

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open The documentation asks for a path to the file. So specify the path to the image and it'll work

Comment: You need to escape the path: `Image.open("D:\\YY_Aadhi\\HED-BSDS\\test\\2018.jpg")` or `Image.open(r"D:\YY_Aadhi\HED-BSDS\test\2018.jpg")`

Answer (score 24):

you can simply do

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("D:\\YY_Aadhi\\HED-BSDS\\test\\2018.jpg")
```

or

```
from PIL import Image
directory = "D:\\YY_Aadhi\\HED-BSDS\\test\\2018.jpg"
image = Image.open(directory)
```

like this.

you have to write escape sequence twice in windows, when you want to define as directory. and It will be great if you try some stupid code. It helps you a lot.

Comment: are you sure write \\ instead of \?

Comment: I'm doing string concordination.I'm sure

Answer (score 3):

Does this `image = Image.open("D:\YY_Aadhi\HED-BSDS\test\2018.jpg")` not do the trick?

Comment: Its giving following error  " Error with image file D:\YY_Aadhi\HED-BSDS\test\100007.jpg cannot identify image file 'D:\\YY_Aadhi\\HED-BSDS\\test\\100007.jpg'"

Comment: This error indicates that there is something wrong with the file. Although it might also be a bug in Pillow, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863145/8488985

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to read an online image

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://somewebsite/images/logo.png'
msg_image = urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work

```
from PIL import Image
import os
'''some code here'''

image = Image.open(r"D:\YY_Aadhi\HED-BSDS\test\2018.jpg")
```

Make sure you add the r letter and also use backslash

if this doesn't work then it could mean your image file path is wrong, use this to get the correct file path

```
from PIL import Image
'''some code here'''

file_name = '2018.jpg'
file_path = os.path.abspath(file_name)
image = Image.open(file_path)
```