# How to view an image captured using Pillow in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow to capture an image on my screen. I would then be able to open up the captured image and view it. However, I encountered a problem where I cannot open the image for a reason unbeknownst to me.

This is my code:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
from PIL import Image


def lswth():
    crnts2 = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(934, 813, 966, 830))
    im = Image.open(crnts2)
    im.show()


lswth()
```

The following code does not produce any images and returns me:
`AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'read'`

I tried viewing other articles about similar problems [How do i read image using PILLOW image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260571/how-do-i-read-image-using-pillow-image), https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-open-method/#, ect. but the problem consisted of an image that was already saved on the computer rather than being taken by PILLOW. I tinkered around the code using other commands like Image.open, Image.save, .load(), ect. but they also returned an error or did not show the image. From what I can gather, the command only works on images already saved on the computer, not images taken by PILLOW. I feel like I have to save the image directly onto the computer but I haven't found a way to do that as Image.save does not work.

How would I view a file saved by pillow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying load an image from your pc. Instead simply do the following:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
from PIL import Image

def lswth():
    crnts2 = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)
    crnts2.show()

lswth()
```

I removed the dimensions you had specified in your own coded but you can place whatever specs you want in there to customise it.