# Image.open gives error Cannot identify image file

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open a geotiff file with PIL's Image function. It raises the error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file 'Whatever\\image\\I\\use.tiff'
```

I saw the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230991/image-open-cannot-identify-image-file-python) for example, the sollutions are to either use

```
Import Image
```

instead of

```
From PIL import Image
```

Which is I think an outdated sollution; I can't import Image. An other sollution is to update pillow to 2.9, but 5 years later we are on 5.0.0. I tried 4.0.0 as well where I receive the same error. 
Is there an up to date sollution for this?

here is my code and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uoz8bzgge5nvdec/rgb_CGI.tiff?dl=0) is a link to a file:

```
image_path = 'each\\image\\I\\use.tiff'

from PIL import Image
Image.open(image_path)
```

Comment: No, `import Image` is not the issue; in the distant past PIL had packaging problems and would not install a proper package (so `PIL.Image` was installed as `Image` instead).

Comment: If the file can't be opened by PIL / Pillow, then it probably is either not in a supported format, or corrupted. Try with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/?

Comment: Another possibility is that this file uses compression, which requires that you have libtiff installed, see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff. At any rate, without an actual file to test on, we can't help.

Comment: I added a file. I can open the file with both gdal and qgis but PIL raises an error. This is just an example though, it behaves the same for every TIFF I use.

Comment: Stick with GDAL or convert to a lower bits-per-sample (up to 16) format, I'd say.

Comment: If you are interested, this is the debug output: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/522f47fa0466d8520ee835bf4006aac4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a multi-channel 32-bit TIFF image, and Pillow doesn't yet support that format. See [issue #1888](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1888):

> Pillow (and PIL) is currently able to open 8 bit per channel multi-channel images (such as RGB) but is able to open higher bit depth images (e.g. I16, I32, or Float32 images) if they are single channel (e.g., grayscale).
>
> [...]
>
> ### Requirements
>
> - We should be able to support common GIS formats as well as high bit depth RGB(A) images.
> - At least 4 channels, but potentially more (see #1839)
> - Different pixel formats, including I16, I32, and Float.

I determined this by using the TIFF plugin image reader directly, with debug mode enabled:

```
from PIL import TiffImagePlugin
TiffImagePlugin.DEBUG = True
with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
    TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile(f)
```

which includes the output:

```
tag: BitsPerSample (258) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 46 - Data Location: 218 - value: (32, 32, 32)
```

(full debug output below)

You can use the [Python GDAL bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) to read this format. You can also use the [`gdal_translate` command line utility](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to convert your files to a format that Pillow *can* handle; for multiband, you'd have to go down to 8 bits, or move to grayscale.

For example, to translate your input file to PNG, you can use:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG rgb_CGI.tiff rgb_CGI.png
```

after which Pillow can open the PNG file.

---

Full debug output from Pillow's TIFF plugin:

```
>>> from PIL import TiffImagePlugin
>>> TiffImagePlugin.DEBUG = True
>>> with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
...     TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile(f)
...
*** TiffImageFile._open ***
- __first: 8
- ifh:  b'II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00'
Seeking to frame 0, on frame -1, __next 8, location: 8
Loading tags, location: 8
tag: ImageWidth (256) - type: short (3) - value: 2924
tag: ImageLength (257) - type: short (3) - value: 2088
tag: BitsPerSample (258) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 46 - Data Location: 218 - value: (32, 32, 32)
tag: Compression (259) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: PhotometricInterpretation (262) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: StripOffsets (273) - type: long (4) Tag Location: 82 - Data Location: 8576 - value: <table: 8352 bytes>
tag: SamplesPerPixel (277) - type: short (3) - value: 3
tag: RowsPerStrip (278) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: StripByteCounts (279) - type: long (4) Tag Location: 118 - Data Location: 224 - value: <table: 8352 bytes>
tag: PlanarConfiguration (284) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: ExtraSamples (338) - type: short (3) - value: (0, 0)
tag: SampleFormat (339) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 154 - Data Location: 16928 - value: (2, 2, 2)
tag: ModelPixelScaleTag (33550) - type: double (12) Tag Location: 166 - Data Location: 16934 - value: (0.25, 0.25, 0.0)
tag: ModelTiepointTag (33922) - type: double (12) Tag Location: 178 - Data Location: 16958 - value: <table: 48 bytes>
tag: GeoKeyDirectoryTag (34735) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 190 - Data Location: 17006 - value: <table: 72 bytes>
tag: GeoDoubleParamsTag (34736) - type: double (12) Tag Location: 202 - Data Location: 17078 - value: <table: 56 bytes>
tag: GeoAsciiParamsTag (34737) - type: string (2) Tag Location: 214 - Data Location: 17134 - value: Amersfoort / RD New|Amersfoort|
tag: ImageWidth (256) - type: short (3) - value: 2924
tag: ImageLength (257) - type: short (3) - value: 2088
tag: BitsPerSample (258) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 46 - Data Location: 218 - value: (32, 32, 32)
tag: Compression (259) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: PhotometricInterpretation (262) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: StripOffsets (273) - type: long (4) Tag Location: 82 - Data Location: 8576 - value: <table: 8352 bytes>
tag: SamplesPerPixel (277) - type: short (3) - value: 3
tag: RowsPerStrip (278) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: StripByteCounts (279) - type: long (4) Tag Location: 118 - Data Location: 224 - value: <table: 8352 bytes>
tag: PlanarConfiguration (284) - type: short (3) - value: 1
tag: ExtraSamples (338) - type: short (3) - value: (0, 0)
tag: SampleFormat (339) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 154 - Data Location: 16928 - value: (2, 2, 2)
tag: ModelPixelScaleTag (33550) - type: double (12) Tag Location: 166 - Data Location: 16934 - value: (0.25, 0.25, 0.0)
tag: ModelTiepointTag (33922) - type: double (12) Tag Location: 178 - Data Location: 16958 - value: <table: 48 bytes>
tag: GeoKeyDirectoryTag (34735) - type: short (3) Tag Location: 190 - Data Location: 17006 - value: <table: 72 bytes>
tag: GeoDoubleParamsTag (34736) - type: double (12) Tag Location: 202 - Data Location: 17078 - value: <table: 56 bytes>
tag: GeoAsciiParamsTag (34737) - type: string (2) Tag Location: 214 - Data Location: 17134 - value: Amersfoort / RD New|Amersfoort|
*** Summary ***
- compression: raw
- photometric_interpretation: 1
- planar_configuration: 1
- fill_order: 1
- size: (2924, 2088)
format key: (b'II', 1, (2, 2, 2), 1, (32, 32, 32), (0, 0))
- unsupported format
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1196, in _setup
    self.mode, rawmode = OPEN_INFO[key]
KeyError: (b'II', 1, (2, 2, 2), 1, (32, 32, 32), (0, 0))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 102, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 950, in _open
    self._seek(0)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1017, in _seek
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1200, in _setup
    raise SyntaxError("unknown pixel mode")
SyntaxError: unknown pixel mode
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I've experimented a little, and the problem occurs when trying to open **CMYK/16** bit images. It doesn't give error with CMYK/8, RGB/8, or RGB/16. Can you elaborate on how to install and use GDAL? It seems more complicated than Pillow.

Comment: I've posted a question about GDAL installation because it seems so confusing. I'd appreciate if could you take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50721107/2202732

Answer (score 1):

I converted the tiff image file from a 64-bit format to a 32-bit format and it worked.

You can do that using ImageMagick 7:

```
magick oldimage.tiff -depth 8 newimage.tif
```

or using ImageMagick 6 or earlier:

```
convert out_0.tiff -depth 8 newimage.tiff
```

Answer (score 1):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) can work directly with TIFFs like this. It loads your file as a mono int32 image with two alpha channels.

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvips
>>> x = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("rgb_CGI.tiff")
>>> x.width, x.height, x.bands, x.format, x.interpretation
(2924, 2088, 3, 'int', 'b-w')
>>> # getpoint reads out a pixel
>>> x.getpoint(10, 10)
[156.0, 141.0, 133.0]
>>> # avg finds the image average
>>> x.avg()
125.31475912560515
>>>
```

It ignores the extra GDAL tags, but you can do all the usual 2D image processing, and it's [quite a bit quicker than PIL](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use).

Comment: FYI pyvips is not a standard module. You need to download Windows binaries and add the bin folder to your path. But it works (where PIL and tifffile failed to load and save my TIF files).