# Python Open TIF Failure Multiple Libraries

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, gdal

I am having some problems opening some .tif files that I have. I've tried using `pillow`, `gdal`, `cv2`, and `skimage`. I would prefer to use `pillow` since I do use it in other scripts. I cannot use `rasterio` becuase when I set up a batch file `rasterio` throws an gdal._version [error](https://github.com/conda-forge/rasterio-feedstock/issues/149) that I have yet to solve.

This opening image error is strange to me since I had another code that split raster images (had a missing data issue so I switched to this one) that uses gdal and has no problem opening it. I read a few posts about how `pillow` does not support certain data types, but I have not any work arounds yet. I've attached the properties of my image and will continue to trouble shoot.

Is there anything that pops out that I need to fix? Again I would prefer to use the first code block I posted (using pillow).

**Pillow**

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from itertools import product

def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out, d):
    Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))
    w, h = img.size

    grid = list(product(range(0, h - h % d, d), range(0, w - w % d, d)))
    for i, j in grid:
        box = (j, i, j + d, i + d)
        out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{j}{ext}')
        img.crop(box).save(out)

tile('name.tif',
     r'D:\image',
     r'D:\images_split',
     1000)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/delete_NA/split.py", line 22, in <module>
    1000)
  File "C:/Users/delete_NA/split.py", line 9, in tile
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\split\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2959, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'D:\\image\\image_to_split.tif'
```

**GDAL**

```
import os
import gdal
from itertools import product

def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out, d):
    Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = gdal.Open(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))
    w, h = img.size

    grid = list(product(range(0, h - h % d, d), range(0, w - w % d, d)))
    for i, j in grid:
        box = (j, i, j + d, i + d)
        out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{j}{ext}')
        img.crop(box).save(out)

tile('name.tif',
     r'D:\image',
     r'D:\images_split',
     1000)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/delete_NA/split.py", line 22, in <module>
    1000)
  File "C:/Users/delete_NA/split.py", line 10, in tile
    w, h = img.size
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\split\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 2184, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Dataset, name)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\split\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 80, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'size'
```

**Other split code with gdal - this one works**

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
# import variables

# Setting the directory
os.chdir(r"D:\ortho")

# Loading in the image
rimg = gdal.Open("image.tif")

# Upper left corner of the minX and maxY
gt = rimg.GetGeoTransform()

xmin = gt[0]
ymax = gt[3]

res = gt[1]
xlen = res * rimg.RasterXSize # units is important UTM or WGS
ylen = res * rimg.RasterYSize

# how many tiles you want to have in each row and column
xdiv = 150
ydiv = 150

# Determining the size of each new image 
xsize = xlen/xdiv
ysize = ylen/ydiv

print(xsize)
print(ysize)

xsteps = [xmin + xsize * i for i in range(xdiv+1)] # plut because we start in the left top corner where X is at its lowest
ysteps = [ymax - ysize * i for i in range(ydiv+1)] # minus because we start in the left top corner where Y is at its highest

for i in range(xdiv):
    for j in range(ydiv):
        xmin = xsteps[i]
        xmax = xsteps[i+1]
        ymax = ysteps[j]
        ymin = ysteps[j+1]

        # Splices the image up into the set divs and saves them.
        gdal.Warp("D:/split_images/item" + str(i)+str(j) + ".tif",rimg,
                  outputBounds = (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax),dstNodata = -9999)
```

[Tif Properties Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvuY3.png)

**Edits**
I ran another image through that is a fraction of the size, with the same properties. Same CRS, Units, Data type, ect. I don't think it would be a size issue because I pass `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None`. One thing to note though, each image that is split, the CRS is not being assigned, which does cause an issue for me later on.

Comment: You do see, that there are missing `'` in `tile('name.tif', r'D:\image, r'D:\images_split, 1000)` (second and third parameter)!?

Comment: @HansHirse Yes, I do see that now. Must have accidently deleted it somehow. Let me update that. But the code I have in my IDLE does have the `'`. So that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that `Image.open()` from `pillow` does not support [BigTiffs](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4513). It also only supports specific [byte sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944819/image-open-gives-error-cannot-identify-image-file). [`tifffile`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) can be used to open BigTiffs. I ended up changing a couple things in my code. First, using `tifffile` instead of `pillow`. Second, changing `img.size` to `img.shape`. Third, `tifffile` opens the image into a numpy array, so use the `clip` method instead. The code does work, though it is not being clipped. This answers my initial question though.

```
import os
import tifffile
from itertools import product

def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out, d):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = tifffile.imread(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))
    w = img.shape[0]
    h = img.shape[1]

    grid = list(product(range(0, h - h % d, d), range(0, w - w % d, d)))
    for i, j in grid:
        box = (j, i, j + d, i + d)
        out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{j}{ext}')
        img = img.clip(box)
        img = img.astype('uint8')
        tifffile.imsave(out, img)

tile('name.tif',
     r'D:\image',
     r'D:\images_split',
     1000)
```