# OSError: cannot identify image file 'file_name'

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have already read answer of this question [Image.open() cannot identify image file - Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19230991/9235408), that question was solved by using `from PIL import Image`, but my situation is different. I am using `image_slicer`, and there I am getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "image_slice.py", line 17, in <module>
j=image_slicer.slice('file_name' , n_k)
File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/image_slicer/main.py", line 114, in slice
im = Image.open(filename)
File "/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2687, in open
% (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'file_name'
```

The full code is:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import image_slicer
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
img = nib.load('/home/user_name/volume-20.nii')
img.shape
epi_img_data = img.get_data()
#epi_img_data.shape
n_i, n_j, n_k = epi_img_data.shape
center_i = (n_i - 1) // 2
center_j = (n_j - 1) // 2
center_k = (n_k - 1) // 2
centers = [center_i, center_j, center_k]
print("Co-ordinates in the voxel array: ", centers)
#for i in range(n_k):
j=image_slicer.slice('/home/user_name/volume-20.nii' , n_k)
```

However `nib.load()`, works fine, but `image_slicer` is not working.

All the nii images are **3D images**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image slicer](https://image-slicer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is not intended for reading `nii` format. Here is the [list](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#image-file-formats) of supported formats.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs whenever the image file itself is corrupted. I once accidentally was in the process of deleting the subject image, until canceling mid-way through.

TL;DR - open image file to see if it's ok.