# PIL unable to identify image file

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library

The object list_of_contents[0] is based64. I am trying to convert it to it's original image.

```
image_64_decode = base64.b64decode(list_of_contents[0]) 
image_result = open('test.jpg', 'wb') 
image_result.write(image_64_decode)
img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\st-am\CANCER_APP\test.jpg')
```

However, I get the following error:

`PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\Users\\st-am\\CANCER_APP\\test.jpg'`

Anybody has an idea why PIL cannot identify the image?

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AhhG.jpg)

Comment: In what line it raises the error?

Comment: Isn't it your problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230991/image-open-cannot-identify-image-file-python

Comment: It raises the error for the Image.open line. The image is in the directory, so I am not sure why it's not reading it