# cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, stringio, bytesio

I am trying to download an image using PIL but its shows an **UnidentifiedImageError**

```
d = login_session.get("https://example.com/xyz.php")
d = Image.open(BytesIO(d.content))
d.save("xyz.png")
```

Here I need to log into a site first and then download an image, so for that, I used **login_session** to make a session

```
  File "C:/Users/dx4io/OneDrive/Desktop/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    captcha = Image.open(BytesIO(captcha.content))
  File "C:\Users\dx4io\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3024, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001A5E1B5AEB8>
```

Comment: Can you say which page you were try to get the image from?

Comment: it's a PHP page for example example.com/image.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image.open() cannot identify image file - Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230991/image-open-cannot-identify-image-file-python)

Comment: I tried with the help of with statement but still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the page you are trying to go to does not return an image. For example, a page which returns an image is https://www.google.com/favicon.ico, but google searching for `image` returns an html page: https://www.google.com/search?q=image.

To test we can try to get an image from a page which isn't an image.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests

notanimage='https://www.google.com/search?q=image'
yesanimage="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico"
```

Now running this code works:

```
d = requests.get(yesanimage)
d = Image.open(BytesIO(d.content))
d.save("xyz.png")
```

but this gives an `UnidentifiedImageError`:

```
d = requests.get(notanimage)
d = Image.open(BytesIO(d.content))
d.save("xyz.png")
```

This code runs without errors:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests
d = requests.get("https://defendtheweb.net/extras/playground/captcha/captcha1.php")
d = Image.open(BytesIO(d.content))
d.save("xyz.png")
```

Comment: yeah, I know but the page which I am telling is just returning a single image but the URL of the image is in . PHP format 
For Example: example.com/image.php

Comment: no, the page must be returning html with a single image in it. Could you give an example of which page you might be using?

Comment: example.com/image.php doesn't return an image...

Comment: This is the image that I am trying to download but this is in .PHP format: https://defendtheweb.net/extras/playground/captcha/captcha1.php

Comment: that works for me... i edited the answer with the code i used

Comment: I don't know but it's not working on my system maybe some python version issue

Comment: what happens when you `print(d.content)`?

Comment: Now it's working fine I think some python version issue