# How to use "from modname import *" to create and modify global names?

Tags: python, import, python-3.3

I have read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) and also [this comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import) but something doesn't work as I expect. I hoped to use `from set_stuff_up import *` as basically an "include" statement to define some boilerplate globals and functions, but something doesn't work as I'd expect. Here is set_stuff_up.py:

```
public_name = None
def set_public_name():
    global public_name # makes no diff
    public_name = 'HELLO DERE'
```

However the following code:

```
from set_stuff_up import *
print('public_name is',public_name)
set_public_name()
print('public_name is',public_name)
```

produces the output:

```
public_name is None
public_name is None
```

In other words, `from set_stuff_up import *` did bind `public_name` "in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs" but somehow the function `set_public_name` operates on a different public_name, regardless of the global statement.

Can somebody clarify the way the namespaces are operating in this case? And is there a way to have the imported function operate on the imported public name?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand that Python variables are names referring to values.  The globals of a module are names that refer to values.  When you use `from set_stuff_up import *`, that means, make names in this module that refer to the same values as the corresponding names in set_stuff_up.  So now you have two names, `set_stuff_up.public_name`, and `my_module.public_name`, both referring to the same value (None in this case).  When you run `set_public_name`, you are reassigning `set_stuff_up.public_name` to refer to a new value.  Your other name, `my_module.public_name` is unaffected.

Names cannot refer to other names, only to values.  Your situation here is no different than:

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

You don't expect b to equal 2 at this point.  Assigning to a doesn't affect any other name that shares the same value as a.

For more detail on this, see [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

There isn't a way to organize your code to get the exact effect you are looking for.  You could use this:

```
import set_stuff_up
print('public_name is', set_stuff_up.public_name)
set_stuff_up.set_public_name()
print('public_name is', set_stuff_up.public_name)
```

Comment: Bitten again by that... this is even more subtle than the "default_arg=[]"  issue. Because the general behavior and the official doc all strongly suggest that `from x import y` does NOT create a namespace `x`, but just "binds" the name `y` in the executing namespace. That's why I supposed that a global in `x` would be a global in the caller also. I thought I "got it" about namespaces, but I also thought "aha, from x import gets around that namespace thing."

Comment: Every module is its own namespace.  There is no process-wide namespace larger than a module.

Answer (score 0):

set_public_name() **global** just apply  in  the set_stuff_up.py scope. **from set_stuff_up import *** is only import the **value** not the reference.

set_stuff_up.py:

```
public_name = None
print('-- set_stuff_up.py "public_name" id',id(public_name)
def set_public_name():
    global public_name # makes no diff
    print('-- before set_public_name "public_name" id',id(public_name)
    public_name = 'HELLO DERE'
    print('-- after set_public_name "public_name" id',id(public_name)
```

try

```
from set_stuff_up import *
print('*** befor call set_public_name public_name id:',id(public_name) )
set_public_name() 
print('*** after call set_public_name public_name id:',id(public_name) )
```

result

```
-- set_stuff_up.py "public_name" id 505816928
*** befor call set_public_name public_name id: 505816928
-- before set_stuff_up.py set_public_name "public_name" id 505816928
-- after set_stuff_up.py set_public_name "public_name" id 12543344
*** after call set_public_name public_name id: 505816928
```

and

```
import set_stuff_up 
print('### befor call set_public_name public_name id:',id(public_name) )
set_stuff_up.set_public_name() 
print('### after call set_public_name public_name id:',id(public_name) )
```

result

```
-- set_stuff_up.py "public_name" id 505816928
### befor call set_stuff.set_public_name public_name id: 505816928
-- before set_stuff_up.py set_public_name "public_name" id 505816928
-- after set_stuff_up.py set_public_name "public_name" id 12543344
### after call set_stuff.set_public_name public_name id: 12543344
```