# import someModule, instead of clr.AddReferenceToFile("someModule")?

Tags: python, import, module, clr, python.net

I am a python beginner (python 2.7 and ironpython 2.7) and not a programmer.
From time to time, I find a code which starts like so:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("nameOfmodule")
from nameOfmodule import someMethod
```

What is the point of this?
Can't we just use:

```
from nameOfmodule import someMethod
```

?

I tried googling but have not really understand the explanation.

Thank you for the reply.

EDIT: the confusion is not between "from nameOfmodule import someMethod" and "import nameOfmodule.someMethod". I edited the code, so that now it makes more sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['import module' or 'from module import'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: Which bit don't you understand, the `clr` stuff or just the `import` syntax?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to `import clr` and `AddReferenceToFile` with recent versions of Python for .NET, but it still works for backwards compatibility so the examples you're looking at might still use it so they work for a larger number of people.

With recent versions, you can treat CLR assemblies as normal Python modules:

```
from nameOfModule import someMethod
```

`clr` is the Common Language Runtime, provided by Microsoft's .NET framework. So, in your example, the script uses `clr` so that it can refer to a component written in C# or Visual Basic and made into a library for use with something else.

http://pythonnet.github.io/ has some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IronPython and .NET? If so the code in the first example is required to add a .NET assembly as reference in IronPython, so that Python can import it.

Otherwise you don't need to do it, and `from nameOfmodule import someMethod` will work.

Note, the code in your second example is incorrect for importing a function in a standard Python module. You can either:

```
>>> import nameOfmodule
>>> result = nameOfmodule.someMethod()
```

or

```
>>> from nameOfmodlue import someMethod
>>> result = someMethod()
```

but the following will give you an error:

```
>>> import nameOfmodule.someMethod
ImportError: No module named someMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you still have to use `nameOfmodule.someMethod(...)` when you want to  call method, in the first you simply need someMethod(..). If you used `import nameOfmodule.someMethod as sm` that would make more sense.

If you like typing or you have another `someMethod` defined somewhere in your code use your second example.

An example using `os.path`:

```
In [3]: import os.path     
In [4]: os.path.abspath(".")
Out[4]: '/home/foo'    
In [5]: from os import path
In [6]: path.abspath(".")
Out[6]: '/home/foo'    
In [7]: import os.path as op   
In [8]: op.abspath(".")
Out[8]: '/home/foo'
```

The clr is only relevant if you are using `Ironpython`:

> The import statement in Python is more analogous to a using  statement in C#. you still need to load the relevant .dll assembly. C# does this at compile-time by using references; IronPython by default includes standard CLR references, which is why it is immediately possible to import System.Xml
>
> However, if you want to load a .dll that is not included by default in IronPython, you must use clr.AddReference("myAssembly.dll") and then use the import statement to import the module.

There a a blog post [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2007_03_10.shtml#e659) that goes into more detail