# Importing a module and using its methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am looking at a snippet of code and I just don't understand how it works:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
```

on the first line pygame is imported, and on the second line, all the methods of a subset of pygame is invoked. If the first line imports all of pygame, why do we have to specifically import a subset of the module again? Why doesn't a mere `import pygame` do the job in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['import module' or 'from module import'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mere `import pygame` would suffice, but the author wanted to have a shorthand access to the constants of `pygame`. For example, instead of:

```
import pygame
...
resolution = pygame.locals.TIMER_RESOLUTION
```

it may be sometimes preferable to have

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
...
resolution = TIMER_RESOLUTION
```

Note that you should still import `pygame` itself to be able to access to other methods/properties (other than `pygame.locals.`) of `pygame`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you can call all the functions in `pygame.locals` without using `pygame.locals.someFunction`, but instead `someFunction`.