# Could not import module written in c# with IronPython

Tags: c#, python, import, module, ironpython

Currently i'm struggeling with writing IronPython modules in c#. At first i have some empty partial class, which represents the module base:

```
[assembly: PythonModule("demo", typeof(Demo.IronPythonAPI.PythonAPIModule))]
namespace Demo.IronPythonAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Demo api module root/base
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class PythonAPIModule
    {

    }
}
```

In some other files, i try to implement the modules:

```
namespace Demo.IronPythonAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Python api module path root (~import demo)
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class PythonAPIModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Python SQL-Module
        /// </summary>
        [PythonType]
        public static class Sql
        {
            public static int executeNoneQuery(string query, string conName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i now want to use the module, it does not work:

```
import demo
Sql.executeNoneQuery("", "")
```

This throws the exception:

> name 'Sql' is not defined

When using

```
from demo import Sql
Sql.executeNoneQuery("", "")
```

Everything works just fine. What did i do actualy wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the difference between **[import and from import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)**

**Demo.Sql** is needed in the first case. So try `Demo.Sql.executeNoneQuery("", "")` instead

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. If IP would do it as i expected it, `import Demo` would be the same as `from Demo import *`, or not?