# reload(Class) in python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, class, module, reload

I want to `reload()` my module in the shell (or in the script) and i am getting an error.
I change the content of my class **defnClass** which is in the file **def_class.py** and want to `reload` it, but get the exception:

```
NameError: name 'def_class' is not defined.
```

The file is in the directory where i have started the shell. Why am i getting this error?

PS: If i restart the shell everything works of course fine.

**my code:**

```
class defnClass:

d = 33.45

def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c

def add(self):
    return self.a + self.b + self.c

def mult(self):
    return self.a * self.b * self.c

def sub(self):
    return self.a - self.b - self.c

def div(self, n):
    return 12 / n
```

I then change this code after having used it, to the following:

```
class defnClass:

d = 33.45

def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c

def add(self):
    return self.a + self.b + self.c + self.div(3)

def mult(self):
    return self.a * self.b * self.c

def sub(self):
    return self.a - self.b - self.c

def div(self, n):
    return 12 / n
```

Then i try to import the new version in the shell after having saved it with `reload(def_class)` which results in the following:

```
>>> reload(def_class)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'def_class' is not defined
```

I have started the python-shell from inside the directory where the **def_class.py** file is.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: first of all, your topic title is "reload(class) ...", in your code - reload(module). Next, if you will try to `from module import class` and then `reload module`, you'll see this error. That`s why i asked for your code. How you import this module?

Comment: I import it with `from module import *`.

Answer (score 2):

> If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import
>   ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the
>   objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the
>   from statement, another is to use import and qualified names
>   (module.*name*) instead.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload

Thats why you should use `from module import class` again instead of `reload(module)`.

But I recommend you to use `import module` instead of `from module import class`, and call class in your code with `module.class()`, and **don't** use `from module import *`.

You can read about this in Mark Roddy answer - ['import module' or 'from module import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: It doesn't work! I still have to exit from the shell and restart it in order to get accsess to the updated module. Maybe does this have to do with python version 2.7.6?

Comment: ok, i think this is something has to do with my emacs setup using **elpy**. I downloaded the python IDLE and it just works fine! But in emacs+elpy it just doesn't work