# python import questions: difference between import a .py file and import a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a little bit confused about the `from xxx import yyy` syntax python. Sometimes import is importing a python file (.py file), but sometimes it is importing a function (def abc) in a .py file. What's the difference between these two types of import?

Thanks!

Comment: You really should read the tutorial on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import