# how to reduce the time of python import modules?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

for example:

```
In [5]: import time
In [6]: def test():
   ...:     t0=time.clock()
   ...:     import pandas as pd
   ...:     import numpy  as np
   ...:     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...:     t1=time.clock()
   ...:     print t1-t0
   ...:

In [7]: test()
10.8699593575
```

on my computer those statements consume over 10 second, 
so when debugging, it's little annoying to run python script using those module.

it's there is good way to solve it?

Comment: You can use `%run` in the IPython shell to run your script.  You don't need to restart IPython between runs, so the modules will remain loaded.  (That said, it only takes 0.2 seconds in a fresh interpreter on my machine once the modules have been compiled to `.pyc` files and cached by the operating system.  Maybe you are short on memory?  Or using Windows?)

Comment: yes, it's ok! i can use those modules happily again !!!

Answer (score 2):

try line profiler to determine which package takes more time:

[image]

Also you may import only the function you need to reduce the time/memory.

[image]

Comment: Good stuff, but screen shots of textual information are a plague. Could you at least summarize the results as indexable, screen-readerable, font-resizable text?

Comment: Using the syntax `from <package> import <module>` is NOT faster, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/710603/2135504 You probably get different results because the library has already been imported the second time you call it.