# What's the difference between these two import statements?

Tags: python

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import tensor as T
```

Is there a difference between the two or are they same? Which is better?

Comment: One difference that I can think of is that if `tensor` is not a module, the first one won't work, while the second one will work whether tensor is a module or a method...AFAIK

Comment: Although the duplicated question isn't exactly the same level, the longest answer's explanation (from user *sapam*) covers the differences in this case.

Comment: I understand the difference between import module and from module import *. My question is about the "as" part.

Comment: `as` is just defining an alias for whatever is being imported. If you are importing the same thing, the affect of `as` will be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not. You're importing the same thing in both cases.

To read up on the differences between `import module` and `from module import foo` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import%20%22%22)

Answer (score 0):

Although the SO posts linked in comments will probably give you the answer you are looking for, one thing I would like to add to the conversation is that the from `import a.b` will only work if `b` is a submodule of `a`, but will raise an error if `b` is not a module.

On the other hand, `from a import b` will work even if `b` is not a module (i.e., if it is a method of `a`). Observe:

```
In [1]: import os.path

In [2]: from os import path

In [3]: import datetime.datetime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8466c53a2255> in <module>()
----> 1 import datetime.datetime

ImportError: No module named datetime

In [4]: from datetime import datetime
```

I think `from a import b` is the preferred usage compared to `import a.b` - at least it is the one that I have come across far more often. The `as ...` part will operate the same in both cases.