# Import Error Python: No module named 'card'

Tags: python, python-import

I've spent the majority of the day trying to troubleshoot this issue. So I'm trying to import the 'deuces' package from github. However, I keep getting an error:

```
!python
```

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> from deuces import Card
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deuces\__init__.py", line 1, in from card import Card ImportError: No module named 'card'

I've been trying to use anaconda and did the pip install deuces. I don't know what I'm doing wrong-- I also tried uninstalling the regular Python and reinstalling anaconda.

The card file is in the same directory so I'm not sure why it can not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

```
>>> from deuces.deuces.card import Card
```

Explanation...

1) Import the module
You missed a level in the directory structure.

```
>>> import deuces.deuces.card as card
```

or

```
>>> from deuces.deuces import card
```

Levels...

```
>>> import deuces             # Module
>>> import deuces.deuces      # Sub-module
>>> import deuces.deuces.card # card.py
```

2) Use the class from the module

Now that you have the module (`card`, lowercase), if you want to access the class (`Card`), simply `card.Card`.

Comment: For additional discussion of python imports, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still receive the same error when inputting what you suggested. Under the anaconda site-packages, the directory is just deuces and inside is card.py, deck.py, evaluator.py and __init__.py.

Comment: Odd (I don't use Anaconda). It'd then just be `from deuces.card import Card ` (`module.card` instead of `module.submodule.card`).

Comment: Do I have to change it in the init file, since thats where the error seems to be originating? Right now in that file it has : "from card import Card 
from deck import Deck 
from evaluator import Evaluator"

Comment: No. That `__init__.py` file is using a relative import from within a module.

Comment: `>>> import deuces; help(deuces)` will show you what's at that level under 'PACKAGE CONTENTS.' You can use this to navigate, e.g. `help(deuces.deuces)` would show you the next level.

Comment: Is there maybe a different way I should try installing it, because no matter what I do, if it has 'deuces' in the command it gives me an error.

Comment: The package author has already made it available via `pip`, so from the command-line simply `pip install deuces`. If you're on WIndows, note that git-bash comes with a command-line.

Comment: Also, to see the import command from the post working, simply git clone the repo. From the parent directory of the deuces folder (which was created by the clone), open python and run the import commands.

Comment: Could the issue be that the module is written in 2.7 and I'm using 3.5? I assumed that I'd have to change the files, but I didn't think there was an importing difference.

Comment: Good instincts; however, this package seems fine on both (I can `import deuces` with both 2.7 and 3.5).

Comment: I got it working on 2.7 but not on 3.5. Ill try reinstalling the module again and do the same thing I did for 2.7 and hopefully that'll do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JJMcGee What'd you do to get it working? Useful for posterity.

Answer (score 6):

I have created a [fork](https://github.com/ihendley/treys) of `deuces` that supports Python 3.

```
$ pip install treys
```

And you can use it with the new name:

```
>>> from treys import Card
```

Comment: This is awesome! Deuces was nice but the developer shows very little interest in it. Thanks for putting this together!

Comment: some prints error and need to be modified by comparing to deuces files. it works fine after that

Comment: Good Work! Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

`deuces` hasn't been ported to Python 3 yet, I suspect.