# getting error when trying to import module from installed package

Tags: python, import, module, package

I've imported a module called 'deuces' (https://github.com/worldveil/deuces) and when I try and import modules from it using:

```
import deuces
from deuces import card
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\botty\dtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import deuces
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\deuces\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from card import Card
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'card'
```

Stating it cannot import the module from the package - but I've checked and the module is definitely present.

Comment: try import `Card` with a capital C

Comment: I'm still getting an error, even if i take the second line out completely I still get the same error.

Comment: delete the first line and keep `from deuces import Card` and make sue the C is capital

Comment: I get the same error with that too.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337024/import-error-python-no-module-named-card