# Python - import file - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-import

When I try and import my file into Jupyter using

```
from fatigue import *
```

it says

```
File "myfile.py", line 189
    def effectiveness():
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It gives this error in my Atom IDE. Also when I try to run it in Jupyter, I get the same error. It is the only error the IDE is showing for the whole `.py` file.

I am just not sure what to do?

Comment: Chances are it is the line above `def effectiveness():` in `myfile.py` that has the syntax problem.

Comment: The information you've provided should not give this type of error. We will suggest you to look just before and after this line, see if you implemented the function properly  or miss-indented somewhere.

Comment: Check if there is any open parenthesis before your method or something wrong before its declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a error in the `effectiveness()` function, inside your `myfile.py`, so when you import this file to your main one, you get that error.

So, first of all, resolve the error back in your `myfile.py`, then it should work fine!
Also, I recommend you to use `import fatigue` instead of `from fatigue import *`, it's much better ;)

Comment: why is import fatigue instead of from fatigue import * better?

Comment: `import fatigue` isn't necessarily "much better" than `from fatigue import *`. It can be argued that it makes your code easier for people to interpret, by explicitly showing what library a function came from, however saying it's "much better" is fairly vague.

Comment: @RunnerBean As I said before, `fatigue.function()` is clearer than `function()`, however that's the only difference.

Comment: Actually, the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) explain why `import *` is not the best choice.

Comment: @RunnerBean: as Siganl said, there's not a huge difference, but in my case is much better, but just as a personal opinion. If you want to know a bit more, take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import