# Maya+ Python: importing maya.cmds

Tags: python, maya

I want to know if there is any difference between:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.polyCube()
```

and

```
from maya import cmds
cmds.polyCube()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the current context there's no difference between `import maya.cmds as cmds` and `from maya import cmds`. Look at [this SO post dated 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import) to know about possible ***pros*** and ***cons***.

Comment: That old post is about a slightly different question, it would be more like the difference between running "from maya.cmds import polyCube; polyCube()" and "from maya import cmds; cmds.polyCube()" (I would def use the latter). As far as I understand there is no difference, although I just had a big argument with bard, which was claiming that "from maya.cmds import cmds" is better, with a long list of made up reasons that didn't make sense.