# global name tkinter not defined?

Tags: python, tkinter

Shown below is the code for a tkinter login window, I'm trying to get a logo to display at the top of the screen, but get this error when doing so:

```
NameError: global name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

Here is my full code:

*original code was here

Thanks

CODE AFTER EDIT (Removing tkinter.):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Speed Wars Login")

def createInterface():
    Label(root, text="Log in").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Label(root, text="Create Account").grid(row=1, column=3)
    #PLACE IMAGE
    canvas = Canvas(root)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=2)
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "logo.gif")
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)

    Label(root, text="Username").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Label(root, text="Password").grid(row=3, column=0)
    global usrnm
    global psswrd
    usrnm = Entry(root, width = 15)
    psswrd = Entry(root, show="*", width = 15)

    usrnm.grid(row=2, column=1)
    psswrd.grid(row=3, column=1)

def loginprint():
    print("Username: %s\nPassword: %s" % (usrnm.get(), psswrd.get()))

createInterface()

Button(root, text="Login", command = loginprint).grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have imported everything from `tkinter` by using `*`. Therefore you don't need to do `tkinter.something`. FYI it's not good practice to use `from module import *`.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import) question/answer for the different ways to import a module and their pros/cons

Comment: What DavidG & the question he linked said. "Star" imports make code harder to read. And they dump all of those names into your namespace. FWIW, a Tkinter star import brings in 136 names in Python 3, and 175 names in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are telling tkinter to import as *, which imports everything into the namespace regardless of its name.

Lose the `tkinter.` at the beginning of creating instances like `PhotoImage` and everything will work.

However, I would strongly advise that you instead change the import to `import tkinter as tk`, that way you can specify `tk.Label`, `tk.PhotoImage`, etc, etc and you won't have to worry about object names conflicting or having to write out the full `tkinter` before each Object used.

Comment: Thanks for promoting the use of `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: The window does open now, however, the image is not displayed, just a blank space where it would be, see my edited code above.

Comment: That's a separate issue, if you can't figure it out, then you should open up another question. 

That said, the first thing I notice is that `photo = PhotoImage(file = "logo.gif")` will be garbage collected, so change that line to `canvas.photo = PhotoImage(file = "logo.gif")` and the following to `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.photo)`