# Python - Best practice of importing modules in the same package?

Tags: python, eclipse

I am writing a package and the folder structure is like:

```
/package_name
    __init__.py
    module_1.py
    module_2.py
```

If in module_2 I want to import module_1, is it better to do

1)

```
import module_1
```

or

2)

```
import package_name.module_1
```

?

Both ways can run successfully. 1) makes more sense to me, because the code is shorter, and also avoids the unnecessary import of `__init__.py` in approach 2). However when I do 1), the IDE gives an `unresolved import` error, despite it can run without any problem. And if I do 2) the IDE doesn't give the error. So I am wondering if 2) is the more recommended approach.

I am using Python 3.6. My IDE is Eclipse + Pydev.

-- edit --

['import module' or 'from module import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)
is an entirely different question. I don't see how my question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I've used relative imports before of form: "from .module_1 import ...". I can't speak for best practice though.

Comment: Worth reading: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['import module' or 'from module import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

Comment: you don't need a best practice. you must write code without a recursive dependency